# Can reviewers view edits made within the 5-minute grace period?

Tags: support, grace-period

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461102/php-logging-script-error), and a user commented that the syntax of the provided code was incorrect:

[image]

I corrected it within the five minute grace period, and consequently flagged the comment as [obsolete] as it no longer applies.

I'm concerned that my flag will be declined on the basis that whoever reviews the flag cannot see that I've edited the answer since it was within the five minute grace period.

Can reviewers and Moderators see all edits made, even those within the five minute grace period?

I asked about this on [The SO Tavern chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/5), and nobody seems to be sure, hence me asking here.

Comment: To address your bigger issue, "I'm concerned that my flag will be declined on the basis that whoever reviews the flag cannot see that I've edited the answer since it was within the five minute grace period": that wouldn't make much sense. A moderator might look at the comment, see that it talks about ending quotation marks, look at the post, see that it does not display any problems with quotation marks, and delete the comment. Or they might delete the comment immediately without ever looking at the post. I can't imagine them declining the flag for not seeing an edit.

Comment: I don't see a problem with leaving a comment like *"Thanks, I've corrected it."* Viewers will know what happened for sure and both comments can be deleted.

Comment: What is the grace period?

Comment: @mjs When you make a post and edit it within the first five minutes, the edit won't show up as a separate edit.

Comment: I'd say just leave it, and let the commenter delete it if they want. Assume comments are generally ephemeral, and actively flag the ones that specifically need removing.

Comment: For anyone reading this thread in the future, please note that this doesn't happen anymore because [comments from other users now interrupt the edit grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/299116), forcing a revision to show in the edit history.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the time this question was originally asked, no, there was no way for anyone else to tell that a grace period edit was made.

These days a comment under a post will prevent any more grace period edits, so as long as the comment is actually posted before the author edits the post, there will be a revision entry for their fix in response to your comment.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that grace period edits overwrite the previous text in the database; effectively making it look like _that_ was the edit.

Comment: More recently, the behavior changed.  Now the grace period immediately ends when any comment is posted.