# Allow flags to interrupt edit grace periods

Tags: feature-request, flags, not-an-answer, grace-period

We sometimes see spam tests and very different users post questions or answers consisting of garbage unreadable content (think *"asdfasdf"*, among other trivialities). These posts are quickly caught by users (and bots) around the website who can then downvote and flag it to hell.

Since we don't want this poster to abuse the grace period we may forcefully end it via a short comment such as *"this is not [a question / an answer] and will be brutally terminated as such"*.
According to [Shog9's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288557/was-the-5-minute-edit-grace-period-removed/288559#288559) the only other way to achieve this would be to post an answer.

The idea behind the grace period is to be able to add small, painless corrections (typos, forgot a word, format or spacing...) without bumping. **Any kind of reaction** to a post (answer, comment) should end this grace period to avoid abuse or confusion.

Flags are a fairly strong reaction to a post.

Even diamond users can't see through the grace, so it can cause confusion if a post is marked as spam, offensive, NAA... but quickly edited to hide the trash.

Could flags also end the grace period?

Comment: Moderators cannot see through the grace period either.

Comment: I have yet to see a case where a troll post was edited to look like an actual answer, however.

Comment: Related: [Can reviewers view edits made within the 5-minute grace period?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285872/can-reviewers-view-edits-made-within-the-5-minute-grace-period).

Comment: This isn't really a bad idea, but I don't see the necessity when comments already function well enough for the purpose.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Do they? I can imagine someone abusing this by pretending an answer was garbage before a grace edit.

Comment: I have seen answers posted that contained a highly inappropriate link (appropriate for the spam flag) that was edited out during the grace period.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Of course. But the logical response to that is "You have no proof, but there's an easy way you *could* have proved it, which suggests that if this happens again, you know what to do, so if you don't do it, your flag is clearly baseless."

Comment: I've also seen entire garbage / spam posts that were edited into shape within the grace-period, usually someone ends up rushing to write a comment "This was edited during the grace period, but it was originally spam" to avoid a declined flag.

Comment: @TinyGiant Indeed ... I'm sure it's quite uncommon, but my one and only declined-spam flag came from a grace-period edit :P.  Ah well!  Even so, I'm not convinced it's enough of a problem to worry too much about though....

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense for the NAA flag to cause a snapshot to be taken if it arrives during the grace period, so you can tell unambiguously what was flagged.

Comment: Pretty nearly anything done in response to a post should end the edit grace period.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have seen a number of answers which started as just a link or 5 short words, which was then expanded to a full answer.  This way they could be first (more likely to be selected as correct), with in the grace period they would fill in the general structure of the answer (no longer NAA) then 30-45 minutes later they would post their finished answer.  Personally I hate it when I start answering a question where someone has done that, because they often incorporate my answer and get credit for being "first".

Comment: Comments end the grace period as well as answers.

Comment: Just becuase @MartijnPieters mentioned not having seen one of these in the wild, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364923) is an example of a question posted with a profane title, flagged as rude-or-abusive, but edited to look like a normal question within the grace period, leaving moderators unable to do much except decline the (valid at the time) flag.

Comment: @meagar: it was bound to happen eventually :-(

Answer (score 23):

**Yes**, flagging a post should definitely end its edit grace period, just like commenting on it does. This feature request is being floated as an alternative to [*Give moderators the ability to see ninja edits*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287808/give-moderators-the-ability-to-see-ninja-edits). For me, this isn't *quite* as useful, but it's probably good enough, and it does handle this flagging scenario:

- User A creates a post with abusive content
- User B flags the post
- User A ninja-edits the abusive content out within the grace period
- Mod handles the flag, can't see any abusive content, and can't act accordingly

That scenario is ***not*** about the flag getting declined. If you flag things, you'll get declined flags, that's not an issue. The issue is that the mod can't see and appropriately handle the abusive content. E.g., if it rises to an actionable level, or is something the poster has done repeatedly, the mod will have the necessary information to do something about it.

And of course, it's not just abusive content, but that's a good example.

So why not just leave a comment to end the grace period? Because flagging is an anonymous process and it's important that it remain so. As [Cody Gray said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331598/dodging-downvotes-by-deletion-and-repost#comment379583_331600) on [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331598/dodging-downvotes-by-deletion-and-repost):

> I *completely disagree* with leaving a comment. There is no reason to get into a confrontation with this person, and that's the only effect a comment will have. They are not simply ignorant of why this practice is sketchy, and you will not convince them. You need a moderator to solve this problem, so flag one, explain your concern, and let them handle it. This is what they are for.

Even if you comment and then delete (and I have no idea if that ends the grace period or if the check for non-poster comments is done later when the edit happens), there's an interval there were the poster is notified of and can see the comment.

Comment: I'd suggest you expand considerably more on why commenting on such posts to kill the grace period preemptively is an inadequate solution in practice.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Done.

Comment: As for your last paragraph: We tested it once in the sandbox. Posting a comment and then deleting it, before an edit occurs, does not kill the grace period. It was a year ago though, things might have changed. The other issue with comments is that diamonds are not very fond of them _(citation needed)_ and they can make review audits too easy (if that's a thing).

Comment: *they can make review audits too easy (if that's a thing)* @Kyll Given the response to every, "Hey, I spotted a thing/mistake/error that made it obvious this post was an audit (was this a mistake)" post on Meta is, "Congratulations, you spotted the audit!", I don't think that anyone's worried about anything that makes audits too easy.

Answer (score -27):

I may well post a link as an answer, and then edit in some more details within the grace period.

Given that a link only answer is NAA….

So the issue is people getting flags declined due to the grace period, as the person checking the flag cannot see that an edit was done.     However often the person checking the flag will not notice the edit even if it is outside of the grace period.

A good case could be made for not allowing NAA flags within the grace period, or at least not adding them to a review queue.  So what if a link only answers lives for a few more minutes.

I think spam flag should end the grace period as we need them to be processed quickly.

Comment: Well, you *shouldn't* post a link-only answer, even if you *immediately* fix it. An answer should be an answer from the moment you post it.

Comment: @Deduplicator, that does not help someone else that is about to post the same answer.

Comment: I never said it had to be a good or long answer, just a minimal acceptable answer (maybe not even a whole sentenc). If you just want to post a "I've got it, hard at work now"-notice which is *not* an answer, post a comment. But even that has *some* quality-standards.

Comment: _"A good case could be made for not allowing NAA flags within the grace period"_ - ehm, no. Questions get bumped when an answer is added, at which moment people will read it. So you better make sure it is a valid answer from the moment it is posted. If you want to play Fastest Gun in the West, play it right.

Comment: Delaying the ability to flag and take down garbage is a non-starter.  Strong disagree, downvote.

Comment: `Given that a link only answer is NAA` ... opinionable. For me, it is a VLQ answer.