# What does "this comment kills the grace period" mean?

Tags: discussion, comments, spam, grace-period

So I encountered this comment during an audit:

> This is spam and this comment kills the grace period.

The question was obvious spam, and the word "spam" was in the link in plain sight.

What does the rest of it mean? Is this a "canned comment"? I may have seen similar, if not identical, comments during previous audits.

Nothing was coming up when I did a meta search for the phrase.

Comment: Smells like Tuna(ki)

Comment: related to feature explained here: [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773). Grace period breaks when a "comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor..."

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Some folks are concerned that a spammer might edit out his spam during the 5-minute editing "grace period" after the post's creation, thus ensuring that it wouldn't appear as spam to future viewers (including moderators) who might thus decline any pending spam flags.

Posting a comment locks in the current revision, ensuring that further edits create a new revision and make it harder for such a clever spammer to cover his tracks.

I'm... Not entirely sure this has actually happened, but I suppose it does no harm.

Comment: Starting from here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29403867#29403867 is a conversation I had with a few folks in chat about this. One example was pointed out, but that was the first time I'd ever seen that.

Comment: Yeah... That was someone jacking around; more trolling than spam, which makes sense. Heh, I guess it's a successful troll if it motivates folks to post these comments forever after. Anyway, the ones I'm more familiar with are the "submarine" spammers who go back and edit their posts a week or so later to *add* the spam, hoping it won't get noticed.

Comment: I see comments like the one Laurel posted _all the time_ in the various review queues on SO, on audits.

Comment: @luke good observation, but in your opinion is that an example of doing harm? Or actually the opposite?

Comment: @Gimby Well as the comments tend to appear on audits - then what's the point of audits? I guess people still have to read the comment(s) on the audit to discover that it's an audit! (if it's not obvious enough already)

Comment: @luke in my understanding the main purpose is to catch robo reviewers or people who are on their way becoming one. In my opinion the comment actually helps to prove that; if you don't see something that obvious, you were reviewing with your eyes closed :)

Comment: @Gimby The term "robo reviewer" is unfair. I could easily make a robot that could recognize this obvious spam. They are more like zombie reviewers.

Comment: It actually happened again today.  It was not spam but a troll who posted gibberish and then edit his answer with plagiarism of another answer.  Without the comment the revision would not have been captured: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36769359/4342498

Comment: Maybe the solution is for flags to kill the grace period

Comment: @Flexo That has been requested: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307402/allow-flags-to-interrupt-edit-grace-periods and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274059/terminate-the-grace-period-when-a-post-receives-a-flag

Comment: The big problem with that is that it's opaque behavior, @flexo. Only the flagger or moderators know what's happening; to anyone else, it'd just look broken.

Comment: How about flags take a snapshot of the post body that only moderators can access?

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know how feasible it would be or if we should but to make it more apparent couldn't the flag button get a counter the the close link does?  It doesn't need to expose what flags were cast but if it showed a number then people would know that it was flagged.

Comment: Had that years ago, @nathan. Large amounts of drama. Also wouldn't really help after the fact.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh I didn't know that used to be a feature.  We don't need more drama.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure what's worse: people posting extraneous comments to kill the grace period or the occasional Meta question asking why the grace period ended early. The latter *does* have the advantage that the first question could become the target of dupe votes later on, and I suspect those questions would be fairly rare. You'd have to know about the grace period in the first place to even ask, *and* you would have to have failed at finding the first one (and ignoring it if suggested while you wrote your question).

Comment: @jpmc26 I find it unlikely that posts worthy of spam/abusive flags have authors who ask on meta about the grace period. And for the very few false positive flags: exceptionally unlikely that OP would edit and miss the grace period.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It would be more likely that someone flagging it or close voting it would. Which of course raises the question of whether close/delete votes should do the same. Also, something else to realize: people are posting meta questions asking about the comments placed to kill the grace period, so we kind of have extra meta questions *and* extraneous comments with the way it works now.