# Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here's a passive-aggressive comment

Tags: discussion, comments

We've got a lot of comments (> 30,000) that follow this pattern:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to ask a question here.

As evidenced by...

[image]
[image]
[image]

This one wouldn't draw much attention since this *does* seem helpful, but the introduction feels unnecessary.

[image]

[There's actually *quite* a lot of these sorts of messages going around to the tune of, "Welcome to" and some variant on Stack Overflow's name](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com:443/savedquery/461762617192:f3c8eed679634b19b8cf2a2c645a535c).

What I see are two problems:

- These messages are intended to be helpful, but seldom come across as such.
- This makes users who give these message come across as elitist or simply regurgitating the same advice which they don't genuinely believe will help the user.

In the vein above, it feels more like an appropriate close vote would do the post more justice in lieu of a comment.  As I understand commenting, it should be used principally to clarify the question.  If the comment is basically offering partial help (or even smarmy help), then it doesn't feel like it has the same impact.

So, my question to the community is:

- What should we do with these sorts of comments?  Flag them as not constructive?
- What should the policy going forward be?

Moonshot:  If it is determined that these comments are less than constructive, could we get them auto-blocked in the future?

Comment: Does "you didn't ask your question correctly" ever come off as non-elitist? You don't give a very convincing argument that these comments are even a problem. They're leaps and bounds better than some of the nasty ones that already do get deleted.

Comment: Those comments are perfectly fine IMO. I don't consider them passive-aggressive at all and they provide constructive feedback to the asker. In all fairness, people who take offense to those comments are likely to take offense to *any* sort of criticism no matter how it's phrased.

Comment: What kind of comments are you proposing to auto-block? Anything that starts with "Welcome to Stack Overflow!"? Or do you think we should set up a machine learning algorithm to detect passive-aggressiveness? And if we implement anything close to your solution (i.e., anything that would make these comments disappear), how do you propose that we educate users as to what they've done wrong? People repeatedly come to Meta begging for comments to go along with downvotes. These people are leaving comments, but yet you're complaining. An appearance of elitism is inevitable when laying out the rules.

Comment: @animuson:  I won't disagree that they're better than the other comments which are *very* ripe for deletion, but they still have a bit of a smarmy vibe to me.  They feel like they're trying to help but ring hollow, which is where the "elitist" vibe comes from; it's as if the asker will by some magic force start using a debugger and their issue will be solved.  Yes, that'd be ideal, but those questions to me scream like they should just be closed for an equivalent reason without the comment.  Hence why I'm asking about it.

Comment: I don't even welcome them to SO. I go straight for the jugular. Nothing passive about it. _Your question/title is terrible. Read here to not suck._

Comment: @Mysticial:  Yes, anyone who takes offense to helpful comments would take offense to just about anything.  I don't have issues with helpful comments.  These don't feel helpful though; these comments feel like they're just there to sort of come across as helpful.  They don't ask to clarify the question stated.  They don't ask pointed, clarifying questions.  At least two of them are faux answers which don't really accomplish anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you're asking a question.  Would you like help?

Comment: @CodyGray:  You should look at the query.  I realize that there's a lot of results to go through, but there are repeats of the *same* "Welcome to SO"-style comment, which only further reinforces my smarmy vibe; it just doesn't feel sincere.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom:  Thanks for cheering me up. <3

Comment: I'd suggest we work together to write some form-letter comments that are sufficiently helpful and polite, but form-letter anything is interpreted as rude by its nature, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom:  That's kind of my point.  This is a bit of a paradox I've had with comments like the one above, which is why I haven't flagged any of them (I think); if we're faced with a question in which the OP genuinely needs to do their own legwork before we can answer, should we *bother* commenting at all and instead close the question with an adequate reason?

Comment: I'm not surprised by the negativity this is attracting for discussing this sort of behaviour - it's the same attitudes that underlie the sort of comments brought up. Perhaps rather than blocking these sorts of comments, a better direction might be "What is the best way to be welcoming and not condescending?"

Comment: @geryan:  Tough love is better than most approaches that we've tried.  We can be firm but kind in many ways, and one of those ways is to discuss matters like this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  I'm not sure why one should bother with those comments, which is kind of the impetus here.  I don't disagree that your methods are more direct, even if they don't always leave me feeling warm and fuzzy, but the real question is, would commenting like that *ever* have any kind of lasting impact?  If it doesn't, why are we allowing it to exist by simply doing nothing?

Comment: Yes, I've asked myself that as well. I can't say I have the best intentions when leaving such comments.

Comment: I had a long battle on non-constructive and sometimes rude comments (see my previous meta), classifying comments during weekends, however of all the non-constructive comments posted everyday on SO at least your examples seem to have a link that can lead to some more info, according to me our biggest problem is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270703/learning-material-c-sharp (>10K since deleted post), but maybe you need to be a parent to understand why.

Comment: @Petter Nope, I'm a parent and I don't understand why.

Comment: It unrustles my jimmies a little to see that 50K users get flogged as equally as a sub 10K user on Meta. Equality for all :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus:  Doesn't really matter who the person or what their reputation is; if the community disagrees, the community disagrees.  Nothing unfair about that.

Comment: @Makoto The SOCVR is maintaining a list of auto-comments [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/blob/master/questions.md). If I understand you correctly those all fall in your passive/aggresive category. Would it make a difference if some of them would get rid of the words *we* and *our* as those can be seen an a way to hide behind the force of a group. Instead those need to be reworded to sentences with *I* and *me* etc.

Comment: @rene:  I've perused the list, and in my opinion, most of those comments seem to exist for the sake of process, rather than them being a natural and truly engaging experience between commentator and OP.  Take the spam comments for example; why should we bother to let them know that flagging spam is better than voting to close (if it's a question) instead of just flagging for spam and letting the rest of the system handle itself?  I *could* see the education angle, but given that there are bans for flagging, I'm not sure we realistically need to step in there.  What value is in those comments?

Comment: The spam ones are there for two reasons: 1. we now and then see users spend close votes instead of spam flags, so that is to counter that effect.  2. we have have seen spam that was edited in the 5 minute grace period. Leaving a comment kills the grace period so if it is edited it explains the spam flags. Overall I agree a bit that the comments might not have much value but it does make the commentor pingable and with that enable them to engage in a conversation. I hope the comments are a bridge between, down voted without comment and the possible salvage of a post and the user who posted it.

Comment: @rene:  It sounds like then that there's a bug or at least a discrepancy in the way spam flags impact the grace period, which would make it more suitable to be reported as a bug instead.

Comment: @Makoto there already is discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321430/what-does-this-comment-kills-the-grace-period-mean) with plenty of links to FR's and arguments from mods and CM's

Comment: Seems like your issue would be largely resolved simply by leaving off the, “Welcome to Stack Overflow“ part. Just tell them what is wrong with the question and point them to the relevant help link if appropriate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "Your question/title is terrible. Read here to not suck." I think you're joking, but for anyone reading this, such a response would be *very* unprofessional and contravenes [SE's guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). There's a big difference between being *direct* and being *insulting*.

Comment: @DewiMorgan If the existing answers seem irrelevant to you now, you are welcome to expand on them or answer totally different angles here. However, please be aware that telling someone that they should read the pages the site makes available about how to ask good question is not a comment that should disappear. It's not "being an asshole"."Being an asshole" here, would be asking questions, ignoring requests for clarity, than whining about it on twitter.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I did indeed write an answer! Poorly. it turns out... :)

Comment: As a new user i can confirm this. My oldest questions include: 70% of "Learn how to ask here" 20% Oh i see you are a new user, marking as not clear what you are asking and 10% of "do you know the basics". And no actually useful answer

Comment: The downvotes to this question reflect the current level of toxicity of the StackOverflow community.

Comment: @Thecave3: No they don't.  They just indicate that people disagree.  There's nothing toxic about disagreeing with something.

Answer (score 83):

> - These messages are intended to be helpful, but seldom come across as such.

... so?

The messages are not a priori snide, rude, nor offensive. They do not generally attack the OP personally. They provide information which is genuinely useful to the OP, even if 95% of those OPs will never, *ever* read those links no matter how you say them.

I fail to see the problem. If someone interprets a polite pointer to information about how to ask questions as being "passive aggressive", then really, there's *no message* that one could give to correct such a person. People who are beyond help are... beyond help.

> Could we get these kinds of comments auto-blocked in the future?

OK, these are canned messages in almost all cases. The users posting them probably have some JavaScript that regurgitates them at a button press or shortcut key or whatever.

So, let's say we could somehow stop everyone who posts such messages from doing so. What do you think they'd do?

Nothing. They'd just downvote/closevote and move on. Why? Because you only post a canned message when you do not *want* to post a specific one. When you've seen the same stupid, insipid crap a few hundred times and have neither the time nor the inclination to post more directly towards the user.

The only thing that blocking such comments will achieve is taking away information that could in theory be *genuinely useful* to the OP. I fail to see how this is helpful to anyone.

> This makes users who give these message come across as elitist...

Well... we *are* elitist. That's what "elitist" means: not being willing to tolerate garbage. If you're not willing to post a complete, narrowly focused question with an MCVE where needed, we're not willing to deal with it.

You follow our rules or you leave.

---

> This one wouldn't draw much attention since this does seem helpful, but the introduction feels unnecessary.

... what? Welcoming a newcomer to the site is unnecessary and should be culled?

When you equate "basic politeness" to "passive aggressiveness", maybe the problem isn't with the comment.

Comment: It feels like you misunderstand me, or we're both misunderstanding the purpose of commenting here.  These comments don't add any details to clarify the question or ask any questions of the OP to fill in missing details.  They're at best faux answers which fill some kind of weird medium between condescending and tolerable for most everyone else.  Don't get it twisted; I don't want any user to come here and post a *terrible* question, but at the same time, I feel it's important that if they run afoul of our **numerous** and **unspoken** rules, they at least have some guidance on what to do next.

Comment: These comments don't feel like they do.  Canned comments are worthless and only serve lip service to those who think they're doing a service.

Comment: @Makoto: "*ask any questions of the OP to fill in missing details*" How is asking for an MCVE *not* asking the OP "to fill in missing details"? "*I feel it's important that if they run afoul of our numerous and unspoken rules*" How "unspoken" can they be if people can link to pages *on this very site* to explain what rules someone violated? The links in those comments provide adequate "guidance on what to do next".

Comment: I didn't mention MCVEs, did I?  I mentioned comments which go along the lines of *not* asking for an MCVE even though they *seem* like they are.  Also, the unspoken rules - well, [Stack Overflow is complicated.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309135/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto: "*I didn't mention MCVEs, did I?*" One of the comments you quoted did, with a link to the MCVE page to boot.

Comment: Fair point.  I must not have noticed that when I skimmed.  I'll say this - that particular comment would be okay if it simply cut the crap, IMO.  I'll clarify that in my question.

Comment: @Makoto: "*that particular comment would be okay if it simply cut the crap*" So... you would rather it just ask for an MCVE, rather than ask for details that are *specific* to the OP's question? You would prefer a canned comment to a specific set of questions?

Comment: No; everything is fine except for the introduction, which feels out-of-place and unnecessary.  In this scenario at least the commentator is *trying*.

Comment: Are elitists not more inclined to only want the best of the best - which we do not enforce at all (good quality is good enough)? Not tolerating garbage is just a base level of quality control, IMO.

Comment: There are some basic rules to follow when you join a community. This is a community and the main purpose is help people that have questions when they are stuck in a programming issue. So, obviously the first thing that you need to learn is "how to ask a question" but some new users ask a question without giving a minimum of information. This is hard for us when we try to help them. I usually ask them "can you give me more info" or "show me your code" but when the case is so bad I will ask them to check the How to Ask first.

Comment: "That's what "elitist" means: not being willing to tolerate garbage."

I think the comments in the OP are fine, but this statement is *dead wrong*. That is *not* what elitism means.

Comment: @user76284 Then what does elitism means?

Answer (score 7):

The comments add nothing because SO itself welcomes new users and points them towards  How to Ask. So a pure welcome comment is just no use.

I often see these comments, with a request for a MCVE, attached to terrible questions, which *do not* have close votes or down votes. It seems that they are used by people who ought to be casting a down vote or close vote but don't want to because they think that is not "welcoming". Blocking those comments and suggesting the poster casts votes instead would improve the quality of the site.

Comment: I'm sure more censorship in the comments is going to help experienced users be more helpful.

Comment: "welcome" is a way to tone down the possible feeling of aggression when presented the rules to a new user. It's a thousand times better than a raw "what have you tried?"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre otherwise it's like being tasked to cross a mine field without a stick to poke the ground with :) Basic courtesy is just like the stick, it prevents explosive situations.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I agree that the first and second comments are less than gentle; the third one perhaps is even border line rude. (Emphasis on borderline.)</strike>

But where you lose me is the second example. It comes across as polite and attempting to be helpful. It doesn't even look canned, as it mentionz explicit details about the post and asks specific questions to help the OP clarify. I cannot think of more helpful comment to a bad question.

If your threshold on "Welcome to SO, your question needs improvement" comments is so high that the second example is deemed problematic, then I think you *really* need to have a hard look at your expectations.

Need to fix this section after question edits.

---

As for comments that *actually* are terse and can be misinterpreted, we should do nothing. The reality is that SO requires something of a thick skin to be a member. That's somewhat unfortunate, but frankly, it's a life skill that's going to apply well outside of SO. If you can't put aside personal feelings most of the time and take a more objective approach, you're going to end up whining about how unfair and mean SO is instead of tapping into the knowledge and (quite charitable) help that users provide. Answerers expect a significant amount of effort to go into a question to make it high quality, and this is a fair expectation for the time they donate. It is not equally fair to expect every word they utter to be as cheery as possible, especially on questions that aren't very high quality.

No user is going to be perfectly giddy to all newcomers who haven't learned how to ask good questions yet. It's nice when it happens, but when we have to sift through as many poorly asked questions as we do, making it an expectation is unreasonable.

If it's blatantly rude or turns into an argument, flag it on those grounds. In other words, if it's a problem bigger than, "This isn't the most nice possible thing I've ever read," handle it as you normally would such a situation. If it's a single comment about, "Improve your question, and maybe this will help a little," leave it alone and move on. The harm done is minimal, and at least someone actually offered *something* for them to look at to improve.

---

If you feel strongly about welcoming new users properly, then demonstrate the behavior you'd like to see. Post a cheery comment on *every* low quality question you come across, and *especially* when another user posts one that doesn't meet your expectations. I suggest using your second example as a guide.

Comment: I should respond to a few things - first, I've isolated and clarified my position on the comment which had the MCVE remark.  That's actually a decent comment to have, but in all actuality could do without the "Welcome" bit since it's not necessary.  Second, I'm not opposed to the "thick skin" ideology, but it does kind of feel like those sorts of comments don't serve the same end as simply closing as unclear or "why isn't this working" does.  I should go back and clarify this a bit more, but I don't feel like these comments are as valuable as a close vote instead.

Comment: @Makoto I actually disagree, vehemently. Such questions should receive a down and/or close vote, but receiving all that negative feedback without so much as a comment is probably *more* frustrating to most new users. If your primary concern is being welcoming, having someone actually *say* something back is going to go a long way further than anonymous, mysterious votes from who knows who. A comment, even a not great one, will be a somewhat softer blow.

Comment: I'm not sure I can see your side there; when the OP says it simply "doesn't work", it's more straightforward to close their question than to comment them through their question (which is what will inevitably happen).  Closure is frustrating, but half-hearted comments cut deeper.

Comment: @Makoto A user who says, "doesn't work," and virtually nothing else is unlikely to respond well to any kind of feedback. (Even if they don't get upset, they probably won't be able to get their question to a point of being answerable.) So sure, it's *simpler*, but for **us**. It's not more helpful to them. A comment, especially one with a link, at least gives them a foothold. A user who gets downvotes and close votes without any kind of other response is likely to just feel ignored.

Comment: I don't think there's any link out there that can guide a user on "doesn't work" besides the MCVE link, which is *provided* in the closure reason.  To further compound that, you'll still run into the issue of users answering the question because "it's easy enough to figure out", even though the OP didn't do their part in providing crucial details.  In that scenario specifically, comments alone *can* do more harm than simply closing it.

Comment: Maybe the issue is more with the fact that anything written loses a lot of context. I dunno for the others posting such comments, but whenever I posted a "Welcome to stack, you may want to read this and then edit your question accordingly" (or whatever form these comments have), I am GENUINELY, 100% welcoming them to stack and pointing them to a helpful article. There is no passive-aggressiveness in it (at least those I write).... if it's interpreted otherwise, then I'll pin it down to the fact that you lose a lot of tone when reading something on the interwebs.

Comment: @Makoto: "*In that scenario specifically, comments alone can do more harm than simply closing it.*" How? In that scenario, the person is going to answer the question *regardless* of whether the comment is there or not. It's not like they were going to ignore the question, then read a comment and went "well screw him, I'm going to answer it". They'd have posted regardless. At least with the comment, the OP knows that someone did not have enough information or was confused. Also, don't forget that closing requires 5 votes; commenting is *immediate* feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I quit the site just because of the "commenter is guilty until proven more guilty" and the "asker can do not wrong" culture you that you clearly present here.

Downvote silently and move on is not even worth it now for the most part unless I am extremely bored and have absolutely nothing else to do while waiting on something for a few minutes here and there.

I proposed a long time ago, just get rid of the comments altogether if objectively neutral comments like these are obviously canned comments are intended are *offensive*, then you will never have a single comment that is not offending someone. Everyone is looking for offense in the current environment because they know they can complain about the slightest thing and get their immediate gratification [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) fix with impunity.

Good luck with this new "culture".

Comment: I think it's not "offensiveness" that's the problem (well, it is, but there're mechanisms to handle it). It's not even that there's a *problem*. But there's something here that could arguably be improved, and if some people are interested in discussing improving it... why not let that discussion happen? Nobody's proposing here anything that'd make your life worse, that I can see. Why such resistance to improving the welcome template?

Answer (score -1):

**Welcoming people is respectful!** Here is an example of a very respectful post.

> First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow!
>
> Now to your question:

However, here is an example of a less respectful comment (Made up to protect identity)

Asker Context: [image]

> Welcome to SO! It looks like you [don't know how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please refer here before asking again

While the comment tries to be helpful, all it accomplishes is belittling the asker.

First of all, the welcoming statement is not applicable to a member of over five years. I actually commonly see newer members welcome veteran members.

Secondly, the body of the reply is extremely disrespectful. Of course, the asker knows how to ask a question; they just made a trivial mistake. Furthermore, the comment does not point out any flaws in the question, it just prompts them to read something again.

EDIT: I changed a lot in this post because people are jumping to conclusions. I conveniently made the first statement bold to minimize the imminent barrage of downvotes, and requiring people to **actually read the post**!

Comment: That seems uncommon, though. Are there so many people saying "welcome to Stack Overflow" towards long time users?

Comment: Surprisingly, yes. The first comment I saw that prompted me to return to this thread was replying to a ~2 year long membership (Subtracted the time since the question was posted). Unfortunately, I'm not sure of any way to directly search comments, so I can't supply numbers

Comment: I agree that such a greeting towards someone who's been for a while is not very nice. Perhaps this is yet another reason not to write it. However, if you put that example of respectful post in an answer, that will likely be edited out, because the greeting is meta-commentary and not relevant to the answer.

Comment: One more note: unfortunately, we cannot assume that veteran users know how to ask questions.

Comment: @E_net4 I find that saying someone "doesn't know how to ask questions"  is quite rude; anyone who is fluent in English can ask questions. (Of course, "question" is a term in and of itself on Stack Exchange).

Furthermore, if a welcoming message is "meta-commentary" (Which I generally agree with), why are people praising it in the comments?

Comment: Never did I suggest telling people that they don't know how to ask questions in their face. But truth be told, every once in a while we get high rep users who ought to be told to hit the usual links ([ask] and [mcve]) after showing a pattern of low quality questions. Not everyone agrees with that loose definition of "being able to ask questions", much less here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding the greetings in posts, although it _is_ sometimes a controversial subject, they are unadvised by the [help center itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Discussion already exists on Meta ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351588/1233251)).

Answer (score -14):

Now that Stack Overflow's arrogant, "suck it up buttercup" attitude of years past is being acknowledged as a problem and addressed, this question seems more relevant, and does not deserve the downvotes it has received.

[Edit: I'm sorry, my above paragraph regrettably displays *the critical importance of tone*: I've likely scuppered any chance of having people see my point, let alone agree with it, through my truly godawful phrasing. I meant it as "SO is way better a place than back when this question was written, with a recent powerful movement to make itself more welcoming," but despite that being the meaning of my *words*, the *tone* came across as saying "SO is a bad, elitist place and you all suck". That's neither what I said, nor what I meant, but it's a reasonable interpretation, and if you read the comments, it's clear that's exactly how people took it, with great umbrage.]

I agree that these comments do indeed come across as "a priori snide", if not actively hostile to new users.

New users are very conscious of social cues and subtext, as they are looking to fit in. They pick up on the nastiness of this template, and read into it more than the person who casually pasted it might have intended.

However, we are told to welcome new users, and no guidance is given on how to do that. These templated answers are all there currently is, to help people obey this instruction to welcome people.

*Some* kind of welcoming comment often needs to be written, but I agree with the OP that the current one feels less than ideal.

What points *should* an ideal template cover?

- A welcome, definitely, but the pat "welcome" that's normally given all too often comes across as a hostile "Hi, you must be new here." How can this be done? I've gone with lines like "Welcome to WorldBuilding Stack Exchange (WBSE), which I hope you will find friendly and come to call Wubbsy." - I feel this is harder to misinterpret as "Hey, you're acting like a noob."
- An address of what is wrong with their question, probably, or you wouldn't be commenting. There are bad ways and good ways to do this. Bad: "VTC: OverBroad: see [Rules]." Better: "Your question will get better-quality answers, and help more people with similar problems, if you split your three related questions into separate posts. I'm voting to close it for now as 'overbroad' (see [Rules]), but don't be put off - this just stops people answering it incorrectly until you've edited it to clarify the one thing you're asking for in this question."
- Then finally a link to more information. A lot of posts, including those in the OP here, do this wrong, putting the "more information" *before* the help, which comes across as hostile: "you really ought to have already read this, but you clearly didn't. Please do so before continuing."

I'm flawed and imperfect. The above is far from the ideal recipe for a welcome template. But I do think that, with discussion, we can do *vastly* better than the current nasty template in wide usage.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with putting user feelings before that of conveying information.  There's plenty of information put in front of users prior to their first post, and they tick a box that says they read it and will keep it in mind.  And...then promptly ignore all of it and continue on their way.  We can't force them to read, but at no point should we accept their behaviour of ignoring the guidance they already got.

Comment: So, what I'm getting from this answer is that we, who respect the site's rules, have to put more effort into our comments than the people who disrespect the site's rules, to ask them to respect the site's rules?

Comment: Unfortunately, compilers and linkers have a 'suck it up buttercup' attitude.  Users who take offense to succinct, terse comments, (those providing useful info, anyway), cannot program computers effectively and should stop trying.

Comment: @MartinJames: "*Users who take offense to succinct, terse comments, (those providing useful info, anyway), cannot program computers effectively and should stop trying.*" Or maybe they realize that there's no point in arguing with a machine, but since people are *people*, people should be expected to be more courteous. That is, they take offense when they see people doing things they would accept from a machine, since people are expected to know better.

Comment: @Dewi: "*the pat "welcome" that's normally given all too often comes across as a hostile "Hi, you must be new here."*" ... if a user is the type of person who will interpret *obviously friendly remarks* as an implied insult, then that's a personal problem. We expect people to assume good faith, and translating a clearly friendly remark as being a tacit insult for being new is not assuming good faith. Attempting to chase such people is not productive; what is welcoming to them one year may be considered condescending the next. Constantly updating messages for them is pointless.

Comment: Nicol Bolas makes a case-in-point. No sugar coating over the comments will help appease users who are ill intended in the first place. Even I tried that, and came to the conclusion that once they have stuck to a defensive stance, it's even best not to comment and to stay away.

Comment: It's not arrogant to say something like, 'suck it up buttercup'. I think you need to 1. go read a dictionary, and 2. stop calling people names. You've been here for 7 years and have only answered 4 questions? You've got no right to talk about SO, you have no idea what it is

Comment: @EngineerDollery: "*You've been here for 7 years and have only answered 4 questions?*" You might want to look at the user's *main account*, not their MSO account. They've got 49 SO answers.

Comment: I like how the very first thing you said here was leaps and bounds ruder than anything being discussed in the question. Did you really feel it necessary to come on and attack everybody, calling the community names in the _fifth word_? Maybe fix that before preaching.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good call that my line can be read as offensive, though I meant quite the opposite: to laud recent efforts to *overcome* the old and now frowned-on "suck it up" attitude; and to suggest that, in the spirit of those efforts, this question from before that movement could do with reexamining. This misinterpretation of my intent underscores how important nuances of phrasing are: it shows I'm clearly far from the best to craft a well-phrased welcome message, but shows how implied meaning really matters, in contrast to some of the claims in comments here. Will edit to clarify!

Comment: @fbueckert: I'm not arguing for acceptance, nor putting user feelings ahead of information conveying. I'm arguing for a discussion towards creating a better welcome template, which is what I understand the OP was asking about. Sorry if that was unclear from my post.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Effort is always going to be put into handling those who are new, and fail. Effort to make a good welcome-comment template that helps them, feels to me like a super-efficient way of helping address the problem. Is your position that the current template cannot be improved in a way that would reduce overall effort?

Comment: @NicolBolas I completely agree that if people take obviously friendly statements and twist them, that's not fixable, and not worth trying to address: that way lies madness! What I'm calling out there is that the apparent sincerity of "Welcome to Stack Overflow." is reduced as the period is followed immediately by a sentence with a contrasting tone, which inserts an "implicit but". Splitting the welcome phrase into two clauses seems to reduce that to me, but (as you can see from how well my post was received!) I'm hardly the best person to advise on at tone :)

Comment: @DewiMorgan _"That's neither what I said, nor what I meant"_ Clearly I cannot speak for what you meant, but that is quite literally what you said. Now reverse the shoes. Perhaps all this "everybody's arrogant" nonsense is the same sort of misunderstanding?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Now that Stack Overflow's arrogant, "suck it up buttercup" attitude *of years past*" - that's past tense, so I didn't quite write what you claim. That said, I *do* deeply regret my phrasing anyway, *it's awful, I'm sorry, and I'm unsure what to do to fix.* I've left it there, with shame, only because my screwup so well illustrates the point I was trying to make. As for whether SO's arrogance problem of the past was merely a misunderstanding... I'm confident you completely get the legitimate rationale behind last year's CoC changes, so I'm puzzled why you'd suggest this.