# Welcome template comment for new posters with poor quality posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Frequently with new posters who post poor quality posts, I add a comment like:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question does not meet the Stack Overflow criteria for a quality question and is likely to get flagged for closing. Please visit the help center and in particular read the section [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to understand the requirements for questions.

It would be great if this could be templated so we can warmly greet new users and point them in the right direction with the click of a button.

Comment: Note that **all** new users always [see this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) before asking their first question *and* have to click a checkbox at the bottom. This page could arguably be improved, but no one can say they weren't offered information on how to ask good questions *before* asking a question :-)

Comment: The name of the site is Stack Overflow, by the way, not Stackoverflow. You can also short link the help center to `[help]`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I wasn't aware of that. From now on, I'll have even less compassion with crap questions from new users.

Comment: Be advised that it might not be appreciated if you welcome new SO users with a "so you decided not to read the [tour], eh? jus' dumpin' your non `[mcve]` problem here an' hopin' for some free code writin', eh?" I tried that a couple of times and it didn't help much either. Chris' suggestion is way better.

Comment: Would anyone *really* mean it if they left that comment, or are they patting themselves on the back for accomplishing next to nothing? Don't leave smarmy comments. For context: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340103/1079354

Comment: I really mean it.  I treat people as I like to be treated, and as a new user to Stackoverflow this is how I would have liked to be treated.   This place is too hostile and it doesn't need to be that way.

Comment: If you are trying to teach new users how to behave, at least spell words correctly in the message.

Comment: @CodyGray - corrected.  However, my intent with this question wasn't to be word perfect - it was to highlight a concept.

Answer (score 6):

Users are *already* pointed to the help center before they're able to ask their first question.  The user posting such a question has already ignored said advice several times along the path to posting their question.

Comment: The advice probably was lost in the enthuasiam/nerves about posting to a new site.  After posting and then relaxing they maybe more likely to read a friendly comment?

Comment: @ChrisSnow So you want to show them how to ask a proper question after it's too late for them to have asked a proper question, instead of while they're actually crafting their question?

Comment: Can new users not edit their questions?

Comment: @ChrisSnow They can.  How many do you think actually do, even knowing that they can and that they need to?  How long do you think it's going to take them to edit the question into a quality question when they don't even know what a quality question is, assuming they actually make the decision to do so?  And again, we're talking about users who specifically ignored all of the information they were given before asking a question.

Comment: Oh, good point. Maybe we should ban new users.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with this. Why? Several reasons:

1. **It requires too much effort** for individual users. In addition to having to read and consider the question, vote accordingly, and decide whether or not to edit and/or vote to close, I now have to leave a comment.

   I suppose the objection here would be that you'd be providing a template to make it easy. However, **if a suitable comment can truly be automatically inserted without any changes in every case, then why not just have the system do that automatically?** Why do I, or you, or anyone else, need to explicitly leave a comment? (And, in fact, [as pointed out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341256/welcome-template-comment-for-new-posters-with-poor-quality-posts#comment430585_341256), this already happens—the system provides plenty of advance help before a new user is allowed to post a question, when they have infinite time to compose and tweak it.)
2. Furthermore, if I leave a comment, that allows users to ping me back incessantly and **gives them *a specific person* at which to direct their rage** when their question gets downvoted, ultimately closed, they don't get an answer, etc. etc. Please, no. I don't need any more of this.
3. Even if you say, well, doing this is optional, I still disagree with it because it has the potential to become too one-sided. **I don't think it is an improvement to have a *single individual* making what appears to be an official judgment about a post's quality**, and that is precisely how this comment would appear to a new user. It's the same concern that I—and others—have expressed regarding *ad hoc* comments of this nature. At least if you're leaving an *ad hoc* comment, you're forced to think more carefully about it than if you just had to click a "Add 'New User Posted Crap' Comment" button. Too many people would do that without thinking.

   **We already have a system in place to deal with low-quality posts.** In fact, we have several of them. One are the flags and review queues. When someone thinks a post is low-quality, they can flag it. That's a single person stating their decision, but it doesn't get immediately acted upon. Instead, the post goes into a queue where it can be reviewed by other users and a consensus can be established. I might think that a post is low-quality, but I might be *wrong*. The review system allows other trusted community members to agree or disagree with me, before a final judgment is issued. **The assessment of quality shouldn't be consolidated into the hands of a single person.** (At least, not without some compelling reason to trust that person's judgment on the question, like holding a silver or gold badge in a relevant tag.)

   The ultimate end for a low-quality question is for it to be closed (put "on hold"). That requires the action—and therefore agreement—of 5 *highly trusted* and experienced members of the community, which minimizes arbitrariness and helps to prevent incorrect decisions.
4. And, speaking of closure, **when a question gets closed, there will be *specific, detailed* guidance displayed** on what is wrong with the question, why it was closed, and suggestions/resources on how to fix it. Isn't that better than a generic, one-size-doesn't-fit-all comment? I think it is. In fact, I think this does everything that your proposal attempts to do, but better because it is tailored to the post's actual problem(s), it has been confirmed by a quorum of 5 people, and it is automatically generated by the system such that it looks official and minimizes the effort required on the part of individual users.

   "Likely to get flagged for closing" doesn't tell anyone anything. Why is it going get closed? How likely? What does that even mean? Why should I care? *What should I do about it?* And "go here to RTFM" (paraphrased) isn't nearly as "warm" and "welcoming" as you make it sound.

If you really want to leave comments like this, there is [a user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) you can use. But in doing so, you take full responsibility for the comments you post and can't hide behind the fact that they are automatically generated.