# Dodging downvotes by deletion and repost

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-answers

I've noticed over time that a certain user, if downvoted, always deletes and immediately reposts his answers verbatim.

Is this legitimate behavior? If no, then what's the appropriate flag, if any?

Comment: But perhaps community will downvote his answer again? Although this is gameplay. Maybe report to moderators would fit. Maybe.

Comment: @yellowantphil He has a mountain of rep. Often his answers are very good, but he tends to answer whether he has a real answer or not, and this is what happens when he's not on point. I suspect the high rep effectively shields him from that type of outcome.

Comment: Note that 10K users get to see deleted answers — they don't vanish altogether.  Also, AFAIK, you don't get back any reputation when you delete a down-voted answer; that DV stays in effect.  So at most they avoid a pile-on effect for down-votes — but there's a bit too much herd mentality (aka 'meta-effect'?) at times on SO.

Comment: I seem to remember you doing this [exact same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406236/shorter-method-to-replace-entries-in-r) a few weeks ago.

Comment: Actually you are doing this almost on a daily basis - here's another example from just a few hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102425/extract-elements-from-a-nested-list-w-o-a-loop/39103243#39103243 here's you two days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070309/installing-r-on-ec2-rhel-7/39070785#39070785

Comment: Note that downvoting is easy (requires 1 second) while deleting and reposting is less easy (requires 10 seconds and possibly constant monitoring of downvotes). I guess the problematic user will grow tired of this behavior soon.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, of course it's not legitimate!

You should flag one of the reposted answers for moderator attention. This might cause a mod to track the author of that answer and suspend him/her if (s)he keeps reposting answers.

Also, [as Sayse mentioned in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/379056), it's a good idea to leave a comment telling the user that deleting and reposting answers just to avoid the rep loss caused by downvotes isn't OK.

Comment: I'd not make that recommendation so easily when you're dealing with someone who has already amassed a large pool of reputation though. They should know better and probably do know better - but still do all the wrong things willingly. In such cases I'd casually point to a meta post about the topic and other than that not make any accusations just to see what the response is going to be.

Comment: I *completely* disagree with leaving a comment. There is no reason to get into a confrontation with this person, and that's the only effect a comment will have. They are not simply ignorant of why this practice is sketchy, and you will not convince them. You need a moderator to solve this problem, so flag one, explain your concern, and let them handle it. This is what they are for.

Comment: `as Sayse mentioned in a comment, it's a good idea to leave a comment` Is it just me or does this sound weird?

Comment: @CodyGray: I wouldn't be afraid to leave a comment in this case.  Their response will be pretty likely to show their true colours, and give some insight into WTF they think they're doing (probably useful for a moderator).  The worst they can do is spam me with comments, or send me angry emails.  Downvotes or edits that deface some of my answers can be reversed, and will just provide further ammunition to justify a ban / account deletion.

Comment: Well, sure. If you don't mind suffering the fallout, @Peter, you can always poke the bear. It will no doubt be interesting for the observers. :-) My point was just that always leaving a comment is not a good idea because it may have undesirable consequences or just waste a bunch of your time, and that getting a moderator/park ranger involved is usually a superior alternative.

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to the above. The user is likely shooting himself in the foot and it might be worth pointing this out to him. [Deleted posts are counted towards questions/answer bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> If a post was poorly-received (downvoted or closed), that will
>   continue to count against your account even if the post is deleted!

So deleting and adding another poor answer is  going to make a answer ban increasingly likely. Normally when I see behaviour like this I point this out to them.

You should also flag any suspicious behaviour like this to a mod.

Comment: I would think it in practice applies only to low-rep users. Getting measurable amount of negative points on answers is pretty unlikely for high rep user, especially one who knows how to game the system.

Answer (score -27):

There should be one exception here:  the case when an answer was downvoted for no real reason, not because the solution in the answer is bad, but because a user is retaliating, or "hates" you.

When I see negative votes on an answer, I do not even test the solution. I believe a lot of us would behave the same.

Thus, removing the answer with negative votes (that do not reflect the quality of the answer) and reposting it anew with minor changes is **not** a way to "dodge" any downvotes, this way you actually **fix** the post and **render SO good service** because future post visitors won't be confused at seeing a correct and working solution is downvoted.

Comment: You do not have any way of knowing who downvoted  your answer, so this cannot possibly be an exception.

Comment: **This is my stand.** I already 1) used Contact Us form and got "sorry-no-help" email, 2) flagged the bad behaviors several times for moderators' attention and received no help, 3) informed a person from SO during an interview of this behavior with no action taken after it. So, this is the only tool to defend our property. This is NOT "dodging downvotes".

Comment: It may not be dodging downvotes, but it is still trying to get them overturned - effectively the same thing.

Comment: Have you considered that none of those 3 routes have had the desired effect because the thing you *think* is happening is not actually happening? I mean, it's pretty wild to just assume the moderators, staff, and everyone else are *completely* ignoring your well-founded concerns. A better explanation is that you are wrong in your assumptions about being targeted with downvotes, especially regarding *who* is targeting you.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, Wiktor. Do you mean Kelly Bundy? I see no evidence of that user ever having downvoted you. If you don't mean Kelly Bundy, then it seems you are inventing groundless accusations. I don't see any evidence that a specific user is targeting you with downvotes. If you have concerns about a user opening duplicates just to post answers, then you should raise a moderator flag on one of the questions, including links to other similar cases in your flag message.

Comment: Thanks, Cody. No, I do not know Kelly. If you have access to our "conversations" with the whole moderator board you know the actual user name I meant. This is not relevant here, I think. Ok, the consensus seems to be "we do not need no-upvote answers that were downvoted with hate downvotes". I will be removing them then.

Comment: @CodyGray if you are specialist, and you know that your answer is right, short clear - then when you get down-votes without comments - it is clear for you that it comes from HATERS. In SO there is a lot of haters - they behaves in passive-aggressive way - community is not friendly

Comment: @Kamil Specialists are often the *worst* people at assessing the clarity of their own answers. It's always clear to them, because they are specialists. However, all of that is besides the point. It does not make one a "hater" to downvote a post. Downvotes have nothing to do with hatred. I've downvoted tens of thousands of posts, and the only ones I ever *hated* are the ones that personally attacked me or other users. Downvoting is not passive-aggressive. There is no aggression at all. It's just a content-rating system; nothing more. There's no possible way that is can be "unfriendly".

Comment: @CodyGray I not say that someone who downvote is hater - this is your concept. Hater is someone who downvote good answer (even without checking it -  or just to do something bad or for [strategic reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast) etc. He downvote not because he know that answer is bad or low quality). I not say that downvoting in general is passive-aggresive - this is your concept. I not say that downvote system is unfriendly - it is your concept. I say that some part of community (errata: not all) is not friendly.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Thank you for your thoughts, I think everyone agrees some downvotes can come from people who do not judge your content, but have personal anticipation to your because of your previous SO actions. The point I was trying to make is that removing such answers and reposting them without downvotes was not "dodging downvotes" to avoid negative rep, but a good and responsible behavior for future SO visitors, who would have ignored an "evidently bad" solution otherwise. Now, when haters actively use "Follow" question feature, this does not seem an effective solution though. .