# Is it OK to re-post the same answer after down-vote or how to deal with jokers

Tags: discussion

Last few months someone (I'm sure that this is the same person each time) constantly downvotes my answers. Of course with no comments.

Maybe someone offended on my criticism or someone who think that SO is a game where you can win so downvoting "competitors" is OK approach to get to top...

Anyway, I've left flags several times, but I got only "helpful flag", "we'll check", "investigation in progress" from moderators...

Nearly two months passed - the "joker" is still not banned

So is it OK to, for instance, to remove already accepted answer which was downvoted and post the same?

Or is there any other way to resolve this kind of "conflict"? Any suggestions?

Comment: If the answer is accepted it cannot be removed

Comment: This is when we really need a moderator named Batman to sic on the joker.

Comment: You have 38 *thousand* rep; why do you care?

Comment: Mandatory: You have no way to be certain who this is, unless someone told you "hey I downvoted you".

Comment: Wait for the automatic voting fraud reversal script to run.

Comment: @NicolBolas downvotes are annoying no matter what. I hate it when I have a CW post downvoted even though there is no reputation loss.

Comment: Just point and laugh, then move on with your life. If the post is truly of good quality and useful, no one user can cast enough down votes to sway the vote totals.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain You *never* have to, nor is it appropriate to use CW a means of avoiding rep loss for an answer, rather than a way of indicating a post is a collaborative work of multiple people.

Comment: Or maybe the downvotes are valid.  You don't know who it was, or why they did it.  Dismissing the votes as a joker does nothing to help you.

Comment: Most of your recent answers have positive rep on them, many of them accepted. So what if someone wants to throw away their own rep and DV some of your answers? I agree with the others -- move on and continue to provide decent answers, as the site members seem to think that you're doing (based on your overall positive answer rep)

Comment: @Servy that's not why I make answers community wiki.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain Yes, your comment made that clear.  Which is why I posted a comment to tell you that that's an inappropriate use of the feature.  If you weren't using it wrong I wouldn't have a reason to post a comment telling you that you're using it wrong.

Comment: @Servy I never even said how I was using it. I'm simply saying that downvotes are infuriating whether the post is CW or not.

Comment: @NicolBolas , because I spent my time to help someone while downvote with no comment makes me feel that my efforts were useless

Comment: @user000001 and what if it's not accepted? Does it make any difference?

Comment: @Andersson you can't self delete an accepted answer

Comment: @Andersson: Yes, the author of an answer can delete it any time he wants if it's not accepted. If it's accepted, the system won't let you delete it by yourself, only moderators or 3 10K users can remove it if accepted.

Comment: @user000001 , I mean not *just delete the answer* but *re-post the same answer if it was downvoted*

Comment: To directly answer your question, no, you should not delete and repost an answer just because it was downvoted.

Comment: @Andersson: I'd say that deleting and re-posting in order to remove the downvote isn't good practice. If everyone did that there would be no downvoted answers at all. If it is truly helpful, future readers will upvote the answer and cancel the malicious downvote.

Comment: *"I'm sure that this is the same person each time"* - why? What evidence do you have?

Comment: @user000001 , this is the only option I have for now :) I was hoping for something more efficient

Comment: If they are from the same person, they should be automatically reversed. If they aren't, they are probably valid votes.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain , once I got two downvotes just one by one in couple seconds : my most popular question + my most popular answer... Do you think it was coincidence? Do you think downvotes were *automatically reversed*?

Comment: They're most likely from the same person if they happened in that quick succession. They may not have been reversed yet, but eventually they should be.

Comment: As explained in the linked dupe, if tthe reversal script is not catching what you think it's suspicous activity, flag for moderator attention and explain the situation.

Comment: @yivi , as explained in my question this approach is not really efficient

Comment: There are no other avenues. If they (moderators and/or community managers) agree that the fraudulent votes have been cast, those will be reversed. If the behaviour continues, stringent measures will be taken against that user. Misbehavior by other users is not an excuse to act out. By deleting your post and repost you could be invalidating legitimate votes, which is against the rules.

Comment: @Andersson welcome to Meta and to *meta effect*. You bring attention to you thus it's logical that you get some downvotes (or even upvotes) after this post. By the way, I don't think you will complain about the upvotes, don't you?

Comment: @TemaniAfif , definitely not, but for now I just got two more downvotes. This is reaction for bad question on Meta?

Comment: not necesseraly *bad* question but this is the meta effect. Many user will see this question and for sure click on your profile, check some of your questions, upvotes, downvotes, etc ... this is the *game*, you can do nothing about it, you are famous now for a short period of time.

Comment: @Andersson - The meta reaction to your post is the result of you suggesting a workaround to downvotes which would be rather unproductive. Having that be the title to your question only amplifies the reaction.

Comment: @TravisJ , my post was not about *searching for workaround to downvotes*, but about *any existed approaches to avoid constant intentional downvotes*

Comment: @TemaniAfif , ok. Next time I'll make a post about *upvotes* hoping for appropriate *meta effect*

Comment: I understand that may have been the underlying issue you wanted to discuss, and overall it was to some degree, however some of your frustration comes through in the title. Leading with "Is it OK to re-post the same answer after down-vote" was not a good way to communicate that discussion.

Comment: I would very strongly suggest it NOT try and harness the meta effect for good. It'll more often than not backfire, and bad

Answer (score 21):

Your main question is largely answered by ["Dodging downvotes by deletion and repost"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331598/dodging-downvotes-by-deletion-and-repost). No, it is not appropriate to re-post answers that have been downvoted, simply to avoid downvotes. This is often flagged by community members and if moderators see this, we typically delete the re-posted answer and undelete the original.

In response to your comments about this being targeting, as a user with over 2000 answers it becomes very difficult for moderators to see any trends in voting towards you when you're receiving isolated downvotes days apart. You've received a total of 9 downvotes in the month of January vs. far more upvotes.

If this is targeted voting, there's aren't many people who I see that have cast more than a handful of downvotes for you, and they've cast nearly as many upvotes for your content. My gut tells me this is merely coincidental activity, and due to you being active in the same tags.

As was indicated in response to the last flag you cast, moderators escalated this to SE employees for review, but it can take a while for them to evaluate unclear voting patterns like this to see if there's anything worth acting on. Again, for a user getting as many votes as you do it can be hard to find clear intent of targeted votes with isolated votes spread across months.

Comment: I agree with you here, however, the 3 recent downvotes are rather clustered; two of them within a minute, and the third within the same 30 minute block as the other two. I am sure the team will figure it out though.

Comment: I don't know where you're seeing two downvotes within a minute, @Travis. I suspect the *very* last three were triggered by this meta post (and involve two different voters), but ignoring those the voting is pretty scattered over the past couple months.

Comment: @Shog9 - Yeah it was the very last three. I didn't realize they were after this post was created, my mistake. I agree the past is pretty scattered.

Comment: @Shog9 , actually only two of three downvotes were made **after** this post. If as you said *two* different voters were involved in *three* downvotes, doesn't it mean that someone made two downvotes?

Comment: Sure does, @Andersson. I don't normally go after two votes; you've done that yourself at least 10 times.

Comment: @Shog9 , so how much subsequent downvotes should be made so they will look suspicious? How much time should pass between downvotes? Any rules?

Comment: No hard rules, but... I have a pretty hard time arguing that votes cast weeks apart with tons of activity in between are part of the same targeted campaign.

Comment: @Shog9 , oh... I see... So after almost 4 years my answers just become bad... Thanks for clarifications

Comment: @Andersson After 4 years someone *noticed* the answer, and felt that the answers were bad.  Maybe the answers didn't age well, and the answer isn't as useful as it used to be, maybe the earlier readers didn't notice problems with the post, maybe the recent voter is more critical, maybe they misunderstood the answer, or any number of *numerous* possibilities.

Comment: @Andersson i mean... that's not entirely unheard of. Things that were the correct way of accomplishing a goal may be terrible now days thanks to advancements in language/tech.

Comment: @Andersson if it was a new upvote, would you think 'those bastards are looking at my answer after 4 years!'? No. You'd just take the vote happily. Why can't it just be the same here? 4 years later someone saw your answer and decided it was downvote worthy.

Answer (score 10):

No, deleting and re-posting the same post just to dodge a downvote is not appropriate behavior. This is just as true of answers as of questions.

It's best to just accept the votes and move on. Life isn't always fair.