# Should an answer that's primarily code from another question be marked Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

I recently noticed a question whose answers were primarily made up of code from another question with slight modifications. Should such answers be marked Community Wiki?

Comment: Why? Were the answers properly attributed? If not, it should be flagged for plagiarism.

Comment: The answers were not attributed, but I wasn't confident in flagging for plagiarism as the code was relatively simple code that the users might very well have written themselves. Though it was very similar to the code from the related question even down to variable names.

Comment: If you raise a mod flag, explain what is done and how it looks like being plagiarized. Brad Larson is known for his fair judgement. Worst case you run into a declined flag which shouldn't be much of problem (assuming you don't have only declined flags). Start your custom mod flag with: *Possible plagiarism:*. Just to be clear: Marking a post as Community Wiki isn't a way to circumvent the CC-BY-SA attribution requirements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since rene missed the answer box by a few inches when posting [his last comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354566/should-an-answer-thats-primarily-code-from-another-question-be-marked-community#comment501121_354566), I'll mostly just echo his thoughts here.

First and foremost, while marking an answer "Community Wiki" is [generally considered appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343086/why-would-you-mark-an-answer-as-community-wiki) in cases where you're drawing heavily on the work of others, it does not obviate the need to provide explicit attribution to the original author of said content. As it says in the footer of every page, all content on Stack Overflow is licensed under [CC by-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which essentially allows the content to be used and reproduced however one wishes, *as long as [attribution is present](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)*.

Therefore, if you ever run across answers that consist primarily or exclusively of content (code or prose, either one) from another source (whether that is an external website or another post here on Stack Overflow) and attribution is lacking (as defined by the above-linked guidelines), you should *absolutely* flag that answer as being in need of moderator attention.

Whether it's actually plagiarism depends, of course, on how "slight" the modifications are. But, as an example, just changing the variable names or the indentation is not sufficient.

To raise such a flag, choose the "in need of moderator intervention" option and type an explanation into the text box that is provided. Rene's idea of starting with "possible plagiarism" is a good suggestion. What's critical is that you provide links to the original source (*i.e.*, where you suspect the content was plagiarized from). A moderator will then investigate the situation, decide if the content was actually plagiarized, and if so, take appropriate action. Moderators have access to more tools for making this decision than do regular users, and they are trusted by the community to exercise judgment in cases like this.

Please don't feel bad about casting flags like this when you see something that makes you suspicious. Plagiarism (or any failure to comply with the attribution requirement) is taken *very* seriously, and we get many such flags, so you won't be alone.

Speaking for myself, and what I believe is pretty common practice, we'll mark these flags as "helpful" if we feel that you had a valid reason to suspect plagiarism. In other words, if the flag makes sense, it'll be helpful, even if we ultimately determine that the answer wasn't plagiarized.

The only case where I would advise you to take extra caution here is one that I saw yesterday: a user flagged an answer as containing code that was plagiarized from another answer to the same question. However, the answers were posted within *minutes* of each other, and the code blocks were so simple that the most likely explanation is the two answerers really did come up with the code independently of each other at the same time. That's only natural, and there's nothing wrong with it. However, [there *still* can be abuse hiding under the surface, even when everything *looks* okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354470/posting-jibberish-then-delete-to-reserve-first-answer), so if you see a pattern of suspicious behavior, we're more than happy to investigate.

Comment: This post by itself serves perfect example what should not be marked as CW - while based on (attributed) content by rene, Cody added a lot of other information and hence this post is not marked CW.