# Undeleting an answer during the first grace-period should refresh the timestamp

Tags: feature-request, answers, revision-history, grace-period, fastest-gun

A few days ago, I made a topic about [Posting jibberish then delete to reserve "first answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354470/posting-jibberish-then-delete-to-reserve-first-answer) that brought up some interesting opinions on the matter. Please have a look if you are unfamiliar with the topic before reading on.

The post was intended more for discussion and to see if people agree it's actually a problem. However, most comments described how the system currently works; only a few suggested how this potential problem can be fixed or prevented.

Therefore, this is not a duplicate of that other question. It is a *feature request*, as opposed to a discussion or support request.

---

**My suggestion:**

*If an answer is un-deleted **within the first 5-minute grace-period**, the "answered" timestamp is updated.*

---

**What problems does this solve?**

The benefit to this minor feature is two-fold:

1. It prevents users from posting answers with nonsense in the body and then quickly deleting it, which secures them the benefit of having their answer being at the top among other answers (if sorted by "oldest first"), thus increasing the visibility of their answer.
2. It prevents the abusive side of this functionality, such as plagiarizing someones answer and then claiming it as your own. Such cases cannot be tracked down nor somehow proven, not even by mods, since this isn't logged anywhere.

What I think is great about this solution is that it doesn't affect the revision history at all. As such, even in genuine situations, such as accidental deletions, your half-baked answer won't be logged.

Undeletions after the first 5-minute grace-pediod will obviously show up in the revision history anyway, so that's not of a concern here.

So...yay or nay?

Comment: They could just *not delete the answer* and still do #2.  That's *always* going to be an issue so long as there's any grace period at all.  Still not much of an issue though.  If someone does this more than once, you're going to notice a pattern real quick that this user is constant involved in plagiarism disputes involving answers posted at almost exactly the same time, where none of the *other* people involved will have such a pattern.

Comment: @Servy, fair point. But that actually requires moderator attention first of all. If none of the answerers brings that up, the questioner is likely to just pick the earliest answer and perhaps give an up/downvote at best. Flags won't happen each time.

Comment: If there are two textually identical answers on a post then *someone* is pretty likely to throw a fit from plagiarism.  If people start blaming the other person in that situation (for having a later timestamp) they're still going to know they didn't plagiarize, and will say as much in the ensuing moderator investigation.  Even if the plagiarist comes out clean the first time, when the same exact thing happens again with another person, and then another unrelated person, it won't take long for a mod to think something's up and maybe this person isn't being serially plagiarized.

Comment: @Servy correct. But why not avoid it alltogether by implementing this, rather simple, feature?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, as I said in my first comment.  They could *still* do it, even with this feature.  It's inherent to the fundamental idea of having a grace period at all for edits.  That said, it's not *actually* a problem.  The site's been this way for many years now, and people aren't actually doing this.  If it *becomes* a problem because people start trying to abuse this, *then* that's the time to consider making a change.

Comment: @Servy well, I've seen #1 already, and not just once or twice. Yes, it's not a problem in the sense that it's breaking the site, but it still leaves room for unsportsmanlike behavior which cannot be tracked easily. I hear you though.

Comment: The first one, as mentioned, doesn't actually *do* anything.  The problem was specifically addressed by altering the sorting algorithms.  That said, if you notice it, flag it.  It's pretty rare (because in a question with enough traffic to *want* to do this, there's enough traffic for someone to notice), and easy enough to fix, and doesn't even have notable negative consequences (not that a moderator won't take a report of it seriously).  The site has lots of *real* problems that are actually affecting people every day; this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Servy I respect your view on this. But I think you're dismissing the topic a bit too quickly there considering how my first post was received. Apparently, many agree something's not right here... perhaps the suggestion above isn't the right **solution**, however the **problem** might still be there.

Comment: You think I'm too quick to dismiss a problem that never actually happens, and that no one even thinks actually happens?  I...disagree.  And that a couple of people upvoted a post because they didn't realize that you're worrying about a problem that can't actually happen in one case, and there are zero documented cases in the other, I'm sticking with no, not being too quick to dismiss.  When you can show that there's an actual problem to be solved, I'll be right on board with you looking for solutions.  I haven't even discussed problems with your solution; you haven't demonstrated a problem.

Comment: @Servy Please, there's no need for the cheeky attitude. 62 people are hardly "a couple". I don't know what precisely made them upvote, but they obviously saw something. Don't take this the wrong way, but I believe you're the first to express any form of disagreement here.

Comment: I agree that Servy is being a bit too quick to dismiss this as something "that never actually happens". We have no way of knowing how often it happens, since the whole point here is that it leaves no trace. Even in just the past week, I've seen several moderator flags raised accusing competing answers of plagiarism. Since they were posted within minutes of one another, I dismiss them as lacking evidence, but for all I know, they did exactly what you describe here. There is absolutely no way to tell. That said, I'd prefer this affected the revision history, rather than changed time-stamps.

Comment: Can't you save the very first copy of answer as hidden revision? Or, better, make a full history of all edits elsewhere, which is deleted after 1 hour or so? Either can prove plagiarism.

Comment: This happened with me just a couple days ago for [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581377/5894241). When I posted the answer there was already an (incorrect) answer with the following text: `var c = 8.0;console.log(c.toString() + '');` But after I posted my answer, not only did the existing answer get updated, but another similar answer was posted. Eventually my answer got downvoted - probably because others assumed I plagiarized from the other answer!

Comment: I personally have **caught people redhanded doing this on multiple separate occasions**, so Servy's statement that the problem "never actually happens" is decidedly false. But I agree that #1 doesn't happen with #2 nearly as often as #2 happens on its own.

Comment: @Sinatr this feature was proposed and declined: [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773)

Comment: Just to add an explicit datapoint (and not just a vote for Bolt's comment): I just had #2 happen to me. Another user posted a solution that clearly was based on a misread of the question. I had posted an answer at around the same time (slightly later), and downvoted their answer. Next thing I know they had edited their answer to *duplicate my solution*, complete with most of the variable names the same, during the grace period. They did introduce an error of their own in the copying (perhaps thinking I had made an error?), but it was pretty blatant.

Comment: I can confirm that the accepted answer was edited 3 minutes 31 seconds after being posted, @NisargShah - but it wasn't deleted or undeleted between being posted and edited, so would not be affected by the proposed solution here.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree, that in this particular case it would not solve the problem. I posted the comment merely because I wanted to point out that these kinds of things **do happen**. Coming back to the question, I remember reading a comment suggesting that the very first version of an answer must always be preserved, and any further revisions during the grace period should write to revision 2. That should solve all these issues, right?! I am not quite sure how complicated it might become though. Perhaps the mods or developers could decide whether it is worth the benefit!

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that's interesting to see people reporting that they've witnessed #2 happen. I guess there is no doubt that this does happen sometimes... but what can SO do about it? Not many suggestions here, I'd like to see some.

Comment: It would create a lot of noise, @NisargShah - editing quickly after posting is *extremely* common; just about everyone misses some typo when proof-reading or forgets to finish a thought, or... If you have real-time updates active, you can see this in action pretty frequently.

Comment: @Shog9 Yup, I understand. I have often done that myself. Probably the plagiarism flag, Cody Gray is working on, might be the right approach for such issues. Other than that, I can think of some client-side (Javascript) solutions such as setting `user-select:none` on answers during the grace period (`setTimeout` for 5 mins) for anyone other than the OP (Question asker), which makes is slightly harder (but not *impossible*) to copy someone else's answer.