# Etiquette: A Corollary to the Fastest Gun in the West

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, fastest-gun

I apologize for giving the negative definition (under **What This Post Is *Not***) before the positive (under **What This Post *Is***). I do so in order to clarify that this is *not* a simple reiteration of some prior posts (like those [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27035/using-a-quick-post-to-get-the-top-then-editing) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143737/are-there-ways-to-make-use-of-se-more-effectively)) on [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), which might *sound similar* and which have been unfavorably received. Feel free to skip to the positive definition.

## What This Post Is *Not*

This post is not about established *rules*, per se, but rather about etiquette and best practices, toward creating informative answers.  This post is not the fruit of cursory research; I have been seeking a normative answer for over an hour.

I am not complaining about strategies used by others to effectively accrue reputation.  Neither am I fishing for viably competitive strategies when "racing" against established users to answer a fresh question.

If *this precise topic* does indeed have an accepted answer, or if it is covered via the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), please know that I made an honest but unsuccessful effort to find it.  Thank you for your patience.

## What This Post *Is*

### My Existing Process

Feel free to skip this.

As a new user of Stack Overflow, who wishes to productively contribute, I often skim the "Newest" feed of coding questions, within the scope of my particular domain knowledge.  My goal is to help where I can, with clear and thorough answers, and in the process accrue enough reputation to exchange illuminating comments and to (eventually) place bounties on questions of particular importance to my job as a (junior) developer.

As a rule, I try to make reproducible and self-contained (ie. omitting no dependencies) the code in my answers. I also document my code granularly, to guide the poster in understanding my process, and I furnish links to external documentation. Where applicable, I include my sample output. Above all, **I test my code before posting it as an answer**, to ensure that it works (as portably as possible) the first time the user might implement it.

Also as a rule, I **edit** my answers for three reasons:

1. To improve readability (by disambiguating my wording; fixing grammar; polishing the formatting; etc.).
2. To correct a functional error in my code.
3. To append an **Update** which introduces a superior approach by either (a) [overhauling my own approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67828515) based on my new insight; or (b) [crediting another user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67826045) with the superior answer.

When editing for readability, I routinely make incremental edits, as I am essentially "cleaning up".  When editing to update, I submit the edit in one fell swoop, as a dynamic "work in progress" would be incoherent until completion and thus unfair to the reader.  When editing to fix errors, the scope of my edits will vary from incremental for the cosmetic (ex. fixing a variable name) to wholesale for the conceptual (ex. mending an overlooked boundary case).

#### In short

While I strive to be thorough, I *feel* that — at the very least — the threshold for **"minimum viability"** in an answer requires that **(1) any code actually work**, and **(2) the "answerer" test such code** reproducibly to ensure (1). Specifically, I *feel* that **"complementary code"** — intended to complete the code supplied in the question — should not throw an error when merged and run with the original code. For inexperienced "askers", I also *feel* that at least *some* explanatory prose is proper in an answer.

### Context

I recently attempted to answer a simple question, posed by a very inexperienced user ("the asker"), that was well within my wheelhouse.

While I typed, I noticed an experienced user ("the answerer"), with ***very*** high reputation, post an instantaneous and hasty answer.  While the answerer's code was technically correct, it failed to import the necessary dependencies: had the asker appended this code to their own in their IDE, it would have **thrown an error** (for the unknown function).  Unsurprisingly, the answer showed no sample output, as the answerer had spared **no time to run (and test)** the code.  Finally, the answer did not contain a single word of prose, either in discussion or as a comment in the code itself; in particular, it made no mention of the missing dependencies.

Given the inexperience of the asker, and the near-certainty of a run-time error, I would not have considered this a **"minimally viable answer"** upon posting. To meet this threshold, I would have included the imports in my code, tested it, and made some mention of its purpose.

Shortly thereafter, the answerer altered their answer with an **absolute barrage** of incremental **edits**: one every few seconds. These edits were scattershot: several rendered the answer nearly incoherent until the remaining edits were complete, a little while later. At no instant in this period would I have considered the answer minimally viable: it simply lurched from one muddled state to the next.

In the end, these edits — which were inevitable and clearly **not inspired by any new insight** — culminated in a coherent answer. This answer managed to include the dependencies, elaborate on the purpose of the code, and display a sample output (which doubtless entailed a successful execution after the answer was initially posted).

The result was that the answerer "anchored" their answer as the top answer — by instantaneously posting it in haste — and then "retrofitted" it — with a flurry of predetermined edits — to meet their own standards.

### The Point

I would appreciate if the Stack Overflow community could clarify the following, especially if encountered as a "foot-in-the-door" strategy to accrue reputation:

1. Where exactly does the Stack Overflow (generally) place the threshold for a **"minimally viable"** answer?  Are my criteria (under **In Short**) too restrictive?  Too permissive?
2. Does Stack Overflow (generally) consider it a breach of the *guidelines* ([**"Answer the question"**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)) — or of etiquette — to hastily post a minimally ***un*viable** answer, merely to "anchor" the answer as the earliest, and then make **predetermined edits** to actually answer the question?  **Note:** I am **not** claiming that the answerer did *this*.
3. Does Stack Overflow (generally) consider it a breach of *etiquette* to hastily post a sloppy yet minimally **viable** answer, "anchored" as the earliest, and then make **predetermined edits** to meet any further standards of accessibility (especially to inexperienced askers)?  I **do** believe that answerer did *this*; and (more generally) that an answer containing exactly two lines of (functional) code — and nothing more — is hardly accessible to inexperienced coders.

Thank you for your consideration!

## Update

In light of some thoughtful responses, which will certainly prove useful to many users, I would like to highlight *my particular* motivation.

There are certain questions that elicit diverse answers of comparable viability, where the asker can select the approach that best suits their needs (ex. processing speed, memory capacity, compactness of code, etc.). However, my example involves a question so elementary that it invites only one meaningful answer, of which all later answers must be a copy—or an unnecessary convolution.

As an **inexperienced user**, I mostly scan for tame questions well within my wheelhouse.  As such, I (and other prudent newcomers) will **engage disproportionately** with such elementary questions until I (we) are more established in the community and (with this validation) confident in our expertise.

And to establish oneself in this fashion, reputation is required...

Comment: As long as you post an answer before the OP reads the answers "earliest" is generally irrelevant. What matters is what's best or what's top of the list when they see it (generally ordered by votes and then randomly for answers with the same score)

Comment: it's an ugly practice, and whose who do it should be ashamed... but the system promotes it occurring and there appears to be no interest in doing anything about it. In the end, it's the result that matters. If they ultimately end up with a good answer, no real harm was done from a content perspective, though it certainly does "suck" for those of us who'd rather create a complete answer from the get go.

Comment: One thing you *could* do to make it blatantly obvious this is occurring is to perform an action that would prevent their edits from being omitted from the revision history. It doesn't solve the problem, but it prevents hiding it.

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for reading!  There are certain questions that elicit diverse answers of comparable viability, where the asker can select the answer that best suits their needs (ex. processing speed, memory capacity, compactness of code, etc.).  However, my example involves a question so elementary that it invites only one credible answer, of which all later answers must be a copy–or an unnecessary convolution.  As an inexperienced user, I mostly scan for tame questions well within my wheelhouse, so I (and other prudent newcomers) will engage disproportionately with such elementary questions.

Comment: Reputation is not a requirement of becoming an experienced user. However, i also want to point out that if a question is so elementary that a dozen people are biting at the bit to be the first to post an answer, there's a fairly high chance that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: Minimal foot-in-the-door answers are permitted, *if* they provide a valid answer in their current form. Also, code samples in answers are *not* required to be complete runnable programs. However, if the code is so incomplete that the OP may not know how to make use of it, then that's definitely not good. And a code-only answer with no prose or explanatory comments is a very low quality answer that deserves downvoting.

Comment: A couple of problems not mentioned is that the first to post a (eventually) great answer gets a silver [Enlightened Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) ([MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened))  and bumps themselves in the [Active Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Active) - depending on which site they are on they might not attract many votes or views in the first few minutes (and there's a grace period) - the reward outweighs the penalty. One upvote cancels the reputation loss of 5 downvotes, and after fixing they can spring back.

Comment: Hi @PM2Ring, thanks for distinguishing those situations! I do understand that code _samples_ in answers are not required to be complete runnable programs. My "stipulation" is that any "complementary code" — an answer intended to complete the asker's program — must work _when integrated_ with the asker's code. Nonfunctional code obviously fails, but functional complementary code still fails when (say) it invokes a function yet (1) it neglects to load the corresponding library; and (2) the asker has not already loaded that library. **Should I edit my criteria for minimum viability for clarity?**

Comment: Your (and the HighRepUsers) approach lack one needed step before answering: **look for duplicates and close(-vote)**. The amount of "easy" questions from inexperienced coders on SO that are non-dupes trend towards zero. Beside that - if an answer in it's current state does noch fullfill your personal minimal viable whatever: downvote.

Comment: *any "complementary code" — an answer intended to complete the asker's program — must work when integrated with the asker's code* I agree. You can edit that into your question, if you like. OTOH, I think most of us here agree that if it's not clear how to use the code in an answer (to the OP, or to a future reader with a similar knowledge level to the OP), then the answer is bad. OTOH, beware of being overly verbose in an answer, as that can be confusing, too. If necessary, have a TL;DR section, then follow it with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Probably it has been suggested before, but I feel that this FGITW problem could almost entirely be solved by giving down-voters their reputation point back if the answer is materially edited after the down-vote, while keeping the down-vote in place. Might be difficult to establish what constitutes a material edit though...

Comment: The "new questions" tab encourages users to write the fastest answer. If you'd rather like to write longer, qualitative answers I'd recommend visiting the "most upvoted questions". A lot of them have outdated or very short answers, adding new answers to those is useful to all, there's no need to rush (and on the long term this also "pays out" reputation wise)

Comment: Concerning "missing imports": My IDEs do that automatically for most things, so I'd say that adding imports is not necessary if it is part of the standard library of the language.

Comment: I must admit: I often expect some co-work of the OP. In many of my answers, my focus is on explaining an concept rather than providing code to copy and paste. Also, I do not always expect my code to run without modifications. This is because I often can not test it. Many of my answers are written on my mobile phone or from my personal laptop - on both devices I might have not the right dev tools installed. Ofc. I usually add a corresponding disclaimer. However I dislike the attitude of many users on SO that they will get production ready code delivered for free.

Comment: Just a small comment regarding "breach of etiquette". I'm not sure it's helpful to use that term until we define what it should imply. It seems to be a moral category but isn't really related to the rules that govern StackOverflow. Does it mean that the related content should be downvoted? We do not limit how people vote or do not vote and also hardly guide them. I'm worried about the real impact that this question will likely have. It may not be much.

Comment: Regarding import statements:  I often leave them out, and I’ve seen others leave them out, simply because brevity makes the code easier to read.  Obviously this is only a good idea if the imports are obvious to anyone who knows the language;  for example, a Java programmer should know the import statement needed for ArrayList.

Comment: In a way the described process of the FGITW seems to resemble a bit the agile software development model. You start incomplete, release early and often, and improve incrementally. It doesn't seem to be a good recipe for answering SO questions, but it surely fits into the current spirit of the time (Zeitgeist).

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for contributing to a great discussion!  While I've tried to make my question as general as possible (ex. language-agnostic), I should mention that I am an **R** developer first and foremost. The _sheer volume_ of non-`base` packages, which overlap in functionality and even nomenclature, can make an unqualified function very mystifying to new R users. If I were to simply write `foobar(x)`, the OP might take a while seeking `foobar` across the internet, with possibly ambiguous results. Thus, I either specify `package::foobar(x)`, or write `library(package)` then `foobar(x)`.

Comment: @VGR Thank you also for contributing to a great discussion!  My [reply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408263/etiquette-a-corollary-to-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west#comment847818_408263) above is meant as much for you as for Jonas Wilms.

Comment: Hi @Trilarion, I appreciate your [caution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408263/etiquette-a-corollary-to-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west#comment847807_408263)! The reason I ask about "breach of etiquette" is because I am new to SA and simply don't know _if there is_ a commonly accepted etiquette for these situations. I ask about it not to morally categorize the answerer, but rather to get a feel for the boundaries — the hard rules; and the softer "best practices" for productive interaction — so I can "start on the right foot" at SA, and accrue reputation with integrity where applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Basically there are rules and activity patterns. The patterns are within the bounds of the rules but they seem to favor a timely publication of an answer. Surely there is a trade-off between quality and production time and an optimum somewhere. Please note that even Cody Gray in his answer does advocate for improving an answer after publication and does not advocate waiting longer than necessary with hitting the answer button. Everyone might have one's own estimation of the best timing but those who publish early seem to not really get a big penalty for it. ...

Comment: ... Maybe they should, but that would basically be a solution to the FGITW problem and such a solution is sought for years without good results yet.

Comment: @Greg - You didn't mean _Given the **in**experience of the answerer_, did you?

Comment: @user15793316 I can't tell you how many times I've been taking my time, writing an answer deserving of a Pulitzer, and when I try to hit the button to post it I can't because the question is closed.  If it's a duplicate I might select-all/copy in the hopes I can add it to the duplicate question, but too often the questions are different enough that my answer isn't good in the new context.

Comment: @Armali Good catch!  I meant to say "the inexperience of the **asker**", who would have trouble deciphering such an answer, and I have edited the sentence accordingly.

Comment: I used to avoid encountering FGITW answerers by avoiding the "new questions" tab.  Instead I had a search for questions in my tags with no answers (and score >= 0) from the _day before_.  I could scan the results for interesting questions and take my time to research an answer with reasonable confidence that no-one else would answer in the meantime.

Comment: @aheze To be fair, I too routinely tweak my posts (questions and answers alike) for clarity, though my edits are made in light of new considerations (word choice, typos, algorithmic oversights, etc.) to posts I considered minimally viable at the time. The goal of my question here was to find the thresholds at which an answer crosses from (1) the minimally unviable or [abusive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354470) to (2) the "improper" (poor etiquette but within the guidelines), and from the "improper" to (3) the generally acceptable.

Comment: I think https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406288/is-it-okay-to-tactically-downvote-downvoting-competing-answers is an interesting discussion very much related to FGITW.

Comment: This is at least one reason why answers should be displayed in a randomized order, not arbitrarily assigning the most upvoted answer at the top. Human (herd) nature is to vote with the current winner even if it isn't necessarily the best answer.

Comment: @Calydon An interesting idea.  However, if the purpose of SO is to be helpful to those with questions, I think that this approach might go overboard, by making it too hard for a new viewer, who has the same question, to find the most helpful answer.

Comment: Well I would have to say (being a very inexperienced dev) that I definitely appreciate full and descriptive answers that I can actually learn from. Programming in general is a very complex world when coming from other disciplines. Any help always is appreciated.

Comment: Me personally: I sometimes do what might look like "foot in the door": I write a short answer and post it. Then I think about it some more, and realise I can add more. Then I think maybe some code would help. As time goes by, my motivation to put in effort grows, and my answer expands. There was never an intention from the outset to do this (and being "fastest gun" never crosses my mind), it's just the same way I approach a lot of my work: small iterations.

Comment: @SteveBennett "being "fastest gun" never crosses my mind" Doesn't have to. Depending on how small the initial short answer was it may still look a bit like FGITW. It's a bit the agile mindset: release often and early. It has advantages and disadvantages. Consumers (the question authors and other readers) get relatively low quality at the beginning, but they know that there is something coming at least. If only we had a way to coordinate ourselves more without posting short answers, something like a public in-production stage. But we haven't.

Comment: Not that I'd argue against perfect answers, but an asker being experienced or not is actually irrelevant, we should focus the post only, not the asker. Though the Stack Overflow the company policy has changed, ex. [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) still says: "_Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers_" (maybe that should finally be updated to include the kindergarden stuff?). That means, that an asker is expected to understand the given answer, even if it's not a full copy-paste answer.

Comment: @SteveBennett I too make iterative edits when improvements occur to me. However, the example I describe involved the answerer posting a stub of an answer, and then immediately altering it with a second-by-second stream of **essentially predetermined** edits. Obviously it's not nearly as bad as [_this_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354470) flagrantly abusive strategy, but I was surprised to see it employed by a **very** prolific user with (consequently) **very** high rep. Since they were clearly a well established user, I suspected this was a matter of etiquette rather than outright abuse.

Comment: Reputation is bupkis. I am coming up on 30000, almost entirely gained in C++. [Herb Sutter of the C++ Standards Committee and author of several books and countless articles and presentations on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1661064/herb-sutter), has about 2000. Side note: The best way to avoid being a fast gun is do what I do: Not be able to type worth smurf.

Comment: Hi @user4581301, I do understand that rep on SO does not correlate perfectly with mastery or authoritativeness in the real world. However — and I'm making an effort to avoid implying their identity — the answerer from my example is both very prolific on SO and **also** an established expert in real life.

Comment: @greg I'm honestly not sure what you mean by "essentially predetermined edits". Are you saying they planned the edits and then drip-fed them? Why would they do that?

Comment: @SteveBennett By "predetermined edits", I mean that the edits were logically inevitable in order to make the question minimally viable; and that the poster was aware of this ahead of time. By analogy, it would be like posting the addends `318732 + 923843 = `, and then later filling in the resulting sum `1242575`. While the exact *value* of the answer would be still uncalculated at the time of posting, the answerer would have known there was only one possible edit to make. Point is, the edits were not the result of some new realization or approach: they were elementary and inevitable.

Answer (score 63):

I agree with you, and in all of my years of contributing to Stack Overflow, I have always followed essentially the same approach that you describe. (Well, generally, I don't test my code. I prefer to just write it in the Markdown editor directly. But I do review it thoroughly to make sure that it is correct and thoroughly explained before hitting the "Submit" button.) **Regardless of what anyone else may be doing, please continue doing what you are doing; it is for the best, both for you, for the asker, and for the overall community.**

Even though some may treat it like one, Stack Overflow is not a race. Our content is meant to stand the test of time. The reputation system fundamentally values *quality*, not speed. While the fastest answerer might accrue more reputation from that answer in the short term, if their answer is not actually the best answer on the page, then they won't be the "winner" in terms of reputation in the long term. Therefore, while it may seem like there's some sort of built-in bias against you, rest assured that is only from short-term effects. Overall, those who write clear, useful, well-explained, correct answers will come out on top. And, even in the short term, it's likely that your answer will be most useful to the asker, which tends to lead to an accept (green checkmark).

As far as your proposal regarding "etiquette", I don't really think this is an ethics issue, but I do think it is good etiquette (and common sense) to make sure that you are submitting a quality answer when you decide to submit. It doesn't have to be the perfect answer—continued improvements are welcome and encouraged. And it seems that no matter how many times I read over something before submitting, there's always at least one typo or unclear sentence that needs to be fixed later. That's just the nature of writing, and it's why we have editing—both collaborative and by the author.

I've long had a *major* issue with people who FGITW a complete turd (this is a technical term) into the answer box. In fact, as a moderator, if I *catch* you doing this (i.e., before you polish it into something reasonable and worthy of submission), I *will* nuke that answer (downvote and mod-delete, which prevents it from being undeleted) for the same reasons that I'd nuke any other exceptionally low-quality contribution. There is at least one other moderator and one CM who will do the same thing for answers that look to be nothing more than "placeholders".

This strikes at something you allude to: what is a "minimum viable answer". I think we all know what it is. [The Help Center attempts to define it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering). Essentially, it is one that is coherent and that provides an actual answer to the question. Source code is *not* required in answers, so if you prefer to quickly post an answer with a brief explanation, and then go back later to add some "demo" code, that's fine. That's a reasonable use of FGITW. So is going back later to add in links (e.g., to the documentation and/or for further reading). And coming back later to add in an alternate approach. And any of a zillion of other things that involve *appending* the answer, not *creating* it.

**If you come across something that doesn't meet our definition (or any reasonable person's definition) of a "minimum viable answer", then please flag it.** It doesn't matter how old it is, or which user posted it. Stack Overflow only cares about content, not metadata. A "not an answer" flag or a "very low quality" answer flag is appropriate on an answer whenever that answer meets the criteria for those flags. If that flag results in the answer being deleted, well, then you've contributed to improving the quality of the site. If the flag gets invalidated because the answer was edited to turn it into something reasonable in the meantime, well, at least the problem was addressed and the quality of content on the site was improved.

The same goes for *downvoting* those answers (when you earn [the privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) to do so). You might later need to reverse the downvote on answers by people who behave unethically, but at least your downvote sent a signal in the meantime that the answer did not meet your standards for a minimally viable answer.

Comment: I really like your answer in general, but let's be realistic, "the reputation system fundamentally values quality, not speed" is simply not true. I've seen enough users get 20K in two months just by machine-gunning answers with little to no explanation and testing. We really do not favour quality. Although with time things do improve but mostly because the community actually notices that you care about what you post and you become more or less known as an SME in your area.

Comment: @Oleg I fundamentally believe what I say about the reputation system. Maybe I'm wrong, I don't know, I haven't done any sort of statistical analysis. This just reflects a deep feeling that I've had over the many years I've been here, merged with empirical observations. The people who post quality content do end up coming out on top, even though others often do manage to get a lot of points from posting mediocre answers. There's room for both, I think. But I really think we do favor quality overall. You could argue that things have changed in recent years, and call me an old fogey with...

Comment: ...antiquated ideas about how the site operates, based on hopes that never quite materialized. But I don't believe that to be so, either. In ye olden days, when there were fewer questions and all the low-hanging fruit had not yet been covered, FGITW was even easier and more rampant. Today, being able to mark these repeat questions as duplicates has tamped down on a lot of the abuse of that feature.

Comment: Cody, well, I do not disagree with you on things improving *eventually* just due to people still being able to recognize good content over the fast & dirty solutions. I just don't think that the system as currently working is *geared* towards quality. I do hope that things are not as grim as I see them but my experience is that consistently those who never cared about quality get rep needed for mod privileges much faster than those who do. I also do see the close feature (and SOCVR initiative) as a blessing. I just think things are getting better *in spite* the system rather than thanks to it.

Comment: Part of it is that the people who care about moderation/curation are spending time (and, in some cases, reputation, e.g., to downvote, but mostly I think it's time) doing *that*, instead of posting answers. Thus, they aren't earning near the reputation that people who are spending time answering are, because they're not setting themselves up to earn rep. So it's not really about quality *per se*, but rather how you choose to spend your time on this site. Equally, if you post all of your answers to Meta like I do these days, you won't earn much reputation on the main site, either.  :-)

Comment: I really hope you are right and I just had a bad experience (I too haven't run any queries on how things are globally). That said, I wasn't talking about those who care about curation more (I understand that be choosing to post here / in chat some forfeit the time spent on SO proper), more about those who prefer quality over quantity. I really do not think the system in its current iteration is geared towards favoring those. Maybe as a result of the outdated answers project things will improve somewhat, but I don't think it will be much.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks again for your thoughtful answer!  After reviewing my post and doing a little more research, I realize that it was a *drastic understatement* to describe the "answerer" in question as having "merely" a *"very high reputation"*. The asker's reputability makes me suspect the fault lies in my own definition of "minimal viability". However — and even *this* is a strong hint to those familiar with logic puzzles — I am hesitant to update my question by *ballparking* (within even a huge margin) the asker's rep, because I am ethically averse to implying their identity even indirectly.

Comment: If we disregard the likely motive (reputation), one *could* see these as just two different ways to use the markdown editor. One person prefers to click `save` often, the other prefers to make many changes in between saves.

Comment: Just a side note about my observations with users who "machine-gun" answers... They usually have a very low badge count compared to reputation.  Meaning that their answers don't typically add meaningful value to other users (quantified by votes, etc.)

Comment: The fundamental mistake in your assumption is that every question stands the test of time, when in reality the vast majority are forgotten five minutes after being posted. You get reputation by answering quickly, collecting those first upvotes when eyes are on it, that's it. There are few, very, very few, questions which really remain actively looked at (and voted on) over time, and those are reputation farms for the "lucky" who won the lottery of answering that question that day.

Comment: An answer I wrote years ago but late proves quality does not always win on a popular question flooded with answers: [how to create a zip file in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/). No answers beside the one I wrote had both a native solution and a way to specify where you want to place a file _WITHIN_ the zip file. Few answers had any actual research behind them, many of them disparaged themselves ie: "This code is an ugly, ugly kluge from olden days. You do not want it." Several even use COM shell objects. My answer has 5 upvotes at #12. We need a hot answers feature.

Answer (score 24):

There's a lot to take in here, but the ultimate question that I *think* you're teasing out is:

"What does Stack Overflow do about answers which are incomplete, unviable or otherwise inappropriate?"

To which the answer, from a technical perspective is **nothing**, because the system itself has no way of knowing any of those things.

The *users* - yes, that'd be you and me - have more power in this in that we can ***downvote*** poor answers to questions, and also flag for spam answers which [actually are spam instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/175248).  So use your judgment when determining if an answer is suitable or not; you're the subject matter expert in this situation, after all!

So...my advice:  if you see someone trying to game the system and their answer *isn't* all that great as a result, downvoting them is the best way to deal with it.  It sends the signal to the system (which needs our help) to start restricting their ability to answer questions.

Comment: Hi @Makato, thanks for reading!  To clarify, my question mostly centered on (1) posting a sloppy response as quickly as possible, simply to be the first poster and so "get a foot in the door" for reputation; and then (2) **editing after the fact**, to "retrofit" the answer such that it meets minimal standards for functionality and common courtesy.

Comment: @Greg:  That happens often but to be perfectly honest, **if the answer provides value, that itself is not a problem**.  It's the fact where someone shoots fast and decides to get something out the door that's trash.  To be blunt, maybe the fact that someone could get an answer out the door within the first two minutes of it being asked is a strong signal that the question is pretty low quality...?

Comment: *If* the answer provides value. Big if right there. But yes, if it does, then it's fine.

Comment: @CodyGray Especial thanks for that clarification!  In the end, the edits made the eventual answer quite solid; I was curious specifically about the practice of cynically "getting a foot in the door" before editing the answer into something acceptable.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks again for the helpful discussion.  Your appraisal is correct: that question in my example was quite elementary.  Thing is, elementary answers will be disproportionately engaged by answerers (like me) who are new to SA, because the prudent among us newcomers tend to build reputation and establish ourselves by posting answers well within our wheelhouse (rather than risking much on a speculative answer).

Comment: Yeah, this definitely happens more often on elementary-level questions. That's an important point, so I'm glad that Makoto is calling that out in a comment. Perhaps it should also be added to the answer, especially given the most recent update to the question? Personally, I prefer to avoid the really elementary-level questions. There's too much competition to get a fast answer, and they're a lot less interesting. I'd rather take the time to solve a harder, more interesting problem; I get more enjoyment (and more learning experience) out of that. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: @CodyGray I definitely agree regarding those intriguing challenges.  When I branch out on SA beyond the parameters of my job — where an urgent problem requires that I maintain commenting privileges and (realistically) place the occasional bounty — I expect I'll feel freer to enjoy the problem-solving for its own sake, without being so conscious of reputation.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but the problem is, downvotes cost a lot more to a low-rep user (OP has 86 rep, I'm sure quite hard-earned from the sound of it) than a high-rep user. I didn't start downvoting answers regularly until I had 10k rep and felt like losing 1 or 2 points wasn't much to ask to make the site a better place. I mention -2 because revenge downvotes are a reality. Sure, all of this is mostly psychological, but it factors in. Also, when answering hunkered down in a snippet, one may not notice other answers going up before it's too late.

Comment: "if the answer provides value, that itself is not a problem" **well, no problem besides**: demotivating new users, incentivizing others to copy your bad example, better answers being stuck at the bottom, a feeling of elitism if high-rep users do this, ... But at least the answerer gets a few more virtual points.

Answer (score 24):

Let me tell you a very common experience which I've had in the python tag. This relates to your question.

For starters, the python tag is *huge*. It has a lot of modules, meaning you'd only be able to answer questions on a few of these modules. Each of these tags have somewhat less traffic than the main tag.

Anyways, a question is asked. It's a borderline closable question, one that's pretty rare. Immediately I look at the question, and I fix their code and make the changes neccessary. I then write up a hefty explanation, making sure the grammar is correct, and the formatting looks good.

When I exit PyCharm to copy the contents of my `.md` file, I see that it has *two* answers. One of which is usually entirely wrong or misleading, and another which is just code with a simple explanation. The answer has momentary value, and is not valuable at all in the long run.

This is the FGITW game. It's what you mention in your question, and it makes getting reputation a real pain.

---

I'd like to adress something which [Cody Gray said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408265/12708583):

> The reputation system fundamentally values quality, not speed. While the fastest answerer might accrue more reputation from that answer in the short term, if their answer is not actually the best answer on the page, then they won't be the "winner" in terms of reputation in the long term.

Realistically, all of the questions asked today (whether it be the regex tag or python tag), are all asked by 1 rep users who don't care for the site. They ask, and the first answer they get is accepted. Then the asker never looks back because, well, they have their answer!

And on many tags (feel free to correct me) the low traffic makes it so that once a question is answered, it doesn't really get revisited. I can say this for sure on the [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter) tag (which is a popular python module used for graphics).

> As an inexperienced user, I mostly scan for tame questions well within my wheelhouse. As such, I (and other prudent newcomers) will engage disproportionately with such elementary questions until I (we) are more established in the community and (with this validation) confident in our expertise.
>
> And to establish oneself in this fashion, reputation is required...

Reputation isn't *neccessarily* the only way to become more established with this community. There are so many things happening in the background, where we stop spam from taking over the network, where we close useless questions, and where we find non-answers that should be deleted off of the site.

You *do* need some reputation to gain access to moderation tools. I'd say the minimum is 125 (flagging, downvoting, chatting, etc.). If you want access to the majority of tools, 3k is probably the way to go, and relatively, 3k is not a lot of rep.

And finally, if you see a high rep user answering questions with half answers to gain rep, just downvote the answer which you see. You only need 39 reputation more to be able to do that.

Comment: Questions get revisited *over time* by people who have the same problem and are searching for a solution. This is why, when you answer questions with general applicability, and you post a good answer that is likely to be extremely helpful to others in the future, aside from just the OP, you are going to accrue upvotes over time, and thus, even if later rather than sooner, will win the "long game" when it comes to reputation. What you say about Qs mostly being asked by new users who don't care for the site is true, but has always been true. It's enough for the answerers to be the ones who care.

Comment: Isn't the point of Python having a bunch of modules so that you can just dash off things like `import antigravity` and `enter_weightlessness()` without needing to bother with loading up an IDE, doing any kind of complex syntax analysis, or whatever else? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, and it is very useful :D. But it takes a while to look through the documentation of each module and learn it. But from what I know, it's easier than c++ :).

Answer (score 24):

My general advice after some 10+ years is to not pay attention to when other answers are posted or how bad/good they are. Or how much rep the person who posted it got, for that matter. Forget about FGITW. If you spend time on your answer it will get rewarded in the long run (if you care about reputation). The user base here may be a snarky bunch (yours sincerely included) but they do appreciate quality.

Quite often I arrive "late to the party" to some question many days old, read the answers and find them lacking in some way. Then post an answer anyway, regardless of if the other answers are up-voted, accepted and so on. This will not stop you from getting up-votes in the long run. Quite often at least the OP will appreciate the answer and maybe change which one they marked as accepted.

And those answers you spent time on will lay there and slowly trickle in up-votes over time.

Personally I'm far beyond caring about rep. The ambition and purpose of the site should be to give answers of high technical quality.

Comment: Also please note that questions that can be answered very quickly are likely FAQ duplicates or uninteresting typo questions. These shouldn't be answered but closed.

Comment: It's easy to not care about rep when it comes in passively without taking any action (which is the result of years of providing good quality answers.) Just answer good questions with good answers and you too can not care about rep

Comment: @KevinB You have to write those answers though... they didn't write themselves :) But it's easy not to care about rep since it isn't actually good for anything. After 20k you've unlocked all user mod tools. But I gave up on user moderation long ago so I don't even _want_ those tools.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the advice!  I should [note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408263/etiquette-a-corollary-to-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west/408264#comment847674_408264): I am a junior developer, and I use this site for research to build solutions, fix bugs, and implement best practices **at my job**. Since I try to be thorough in my (hours of) research, I expect the questions I eventually _do_ post will be unanswered, idiosyncratic, and tricky. Nonetheless, these questions might be urgent, and **bounties** (reputation) can be needed to promptly attract answers of high quality.

Comment: @Greg The bounty mechanic is silly, I never paid attention to it personally. It's mostly just used as a way to gift rep to other users. If you want a question to get more attention, it is more important to use a good title and correct tags.

Comment: @Lundin Ironically, I might just be on the verge of bountying [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172274/conditionally-override-default-arguments-when-passing-masked-variables-in) of mine. This is a rather frustrating challenge made complex by technicalities, and few people seem to have read the necessary details. While I have used a hint in an answer to hack together my own non-canonical solution, I am still actively seeking answers that are truly stable, extensible, and canonical in form. Should I take my own solution to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Greg If you have a complete and working code, then sure. Code Review isn't nearly as spammy as SO, so you will almost certainly get responses.

Answer (score 17):

To avoid the FGITW issue, I try to do the exact opposite: instead of rushing to answer new questions, I check **old** questions that have no answers. Of course, you'll find questions of dubious quality, but every once in a while, you'll find very interesting and difficult questions that are very rewarding to answer. Those questions can also lead to a great reputation boost.

Since these are old questions, you can be sure that no one is also trying to answer, so you can take as much time as needed to write your answer. One added benefit if you care about this kind of thing is that you can earn the [Necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

Comment: Yes, that's what one usually has to do to avoid the omnipresent FGITW. Methinks most of those 746183 users employ a similar tactic (I am one of them as well) from time to time. It is also much more satisfying to get a reply from the OP that asked a question N years ago that they thought they'd never get an answer to that.

Answer (score 5):

While a FGITW cowboy might post like that, there's another, similar concept to keep in mind - FDITW (fastest *downvote* in the west).  They might eventually end up with a good quality answer but in the meantime, it's an incoherent blob of garbage.  People reading the answer will give it the downvote it deserves.

It's very rare for someone to go back and re-evaluate things that they downvoted in the past.  That means those early downvotes end up sticking, even if the final version is upvote-worthy.

Answering questions like that is a gamble.  You'd technically be the first to answer, but at the same time you create a window of time where you're very likely to get downvoted.  Compare that to the way that *you* write answers, where only the final product is visible and no such intermediate garbage state is publicly visible.  Assuming both answers are correct you'll end up with similar upvote counts, but the other guy will still be saddled with those early downvotes.  Thus, your answer gets ranked higher.

You have to weigh the benefits of being the first answer against the likelihood that someone will read the question and downvote your answer-in-progress before you're finished.  I, personally, don't see any advantage unless you're hunting a specific badge for some reason, but that should be pretty rare.

If this was a *huge* problem, the site could limit how many times you can edit a question/answer in a certain period of time.  The only reasons I can think of for an answer being edited every few seconds are people posting like this, defacement/bots, edit wars, or someone who doesn't understand how the "preview" feature works.  None of those seem like use cases that need to be preserved.

Comment: A meaningful point, but for simpler questions (only some of which are duplicates) that window of time is *very* narrow, and the asker will likely use timestamp as a tiebreaker when accepting an answer from candidates of comparable quality.  There also the potential for the ["Sleeper Strategy"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354470), which dodges those downvotes by "hiding" until finishing and undeleting the answer. Since users rarely view the edit history on an answer, the latter strategy might also cast a plagiarized answer as the *plagiarizer*, also by virtue of the timestamp.

Comment: Now given my limited SO experience, I cannot say whether this strategy is prolific across SO, but I doubt the window — between the initial post and the edit that reaches "minimum viability" — is wide enough to make the downvotes a prohibitive deterrent for nimble answerers. In my example, that window lasted roughly 1 minute, and it takes a few moments (since the initial posting) to even *read* the answer, let alone make the considerations for a downvote or flag. I have to say: if the answerer from my example does employ this strategy regularly, it has certainly proven **_wildly_** successful.

Comment: @Greg Even if the question asker uses the "created" timestamp instead of the "modified" timestamp to resolve a tie for the "accepted" bonus, it's usually irrelevant in the long run.  The amount of rep you get from having your answer accepted is dwarfed by the rep you get from providing a quality answer that gets lots of upvotes. If the question gets so little traffic that the "accepted" bonus is significant, than it's probably a question that wasn't worth spending that much time on in the first place.

Comment: @Greg If all of those edits took place over roughly a minute, then I'd think this was someone who didn't know how to preview their post without submitting it (posting on a mobile device maybe?).  I wonder if someone with more database-fu than I can use the site's analysis tools and query how many answers get edited more than X amount of times in a Y minute window by the same person.  That would be a good indicator of how common this is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  To discuss your point — *"The amount of rep you get from having your answer accepted is dwarfed"* — I should note that this answerer has answered a metric ton of questions, many of an elementary nature, and they rank among the most prolific on SO.  Given their years of experience, I'm not sure they were *"someone who didn't know how to preview their post"*.  Then again, I have no info to suggest they employ the edit barrage on a routine basis.

Comment: After a month of observation — this user and I cross paths routinely on new questions in my specialty — I can say that: **(1)** This user is an institutional expert in their field, and they hold most of the badges on Stack Overflow. **(2)** This user rapidly posts dozens of "lean" answers daily, with "predetermined edits" every couple days. **(3)** The questions are mostly elementary, and the answers rarely garner more than a handful of upvotes beyond acceptance. **(4)** By sheer volume, this user accrues hundreds daily in rep. My theory is that they're angling for a reputation milestone...

Answer (score 3):

My approach is simple.

If an answer is bad (code would throw an obvious error or logic does not result in outcome desired by OP) then I downvote; no constructive comment, they don't deserve one. If I'm sticking around and writing an answer then I'll check if the answer was edited into something coherent and remove my downvote before I move on to other things.

If an answer properly answers the question but provides minimal or no explanation then I leave it be (no vote) and provide a comment suggesting that their answer would benefit from an explanation.

---

I participate in the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag and more often than not will provide a [regex-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67877573/2191572) and it usually suffices since I supply working proof at regex101. Occasionally someone will ask for an explanation so I do try to oblige.

However, if I feel the need to explain a regex off the bat then I will do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414289/2191572

Occasionally, I will post just the regex with a note saying "Explanation will be provided shortly" if I want to just get the answer out there and if someone wants the explanation then they just have to wait. Sometimes my explanation can take 15-20 minutes to write and I'd be lying if I said gamification is not a motivating factor =)