# A suggestion about simple questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, new-users, users

Do you think you can request experienced users to leave the question to new users if the question is simple, something like this?

To answer the questions posed by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

- Your question asks for a policy change but provides no information in support of, offers no rationale for this request, which begs the question -- why make the suggestion?

You are right. The intention was to in a way promote friendly small competition so that people who are learning something new **in that given area**. It is not about the age. It is about where you are at that point in that area.

- who is "old" and who is "young"?

You are the one; one who is answering. It's completely up to you. The phrase "young ones" was not supposed to be derogatory or condescending, but just as a way to ease suggestion with humour.

- Why should there be limits to anyone answering a question?

There isn't. It's a suggestion; not a restriction.

- Why would it matter who was "first" to answer a question?

Same as above.

- What about the question asker and the future visitors with similar problems?

This is **not** a restriction of any sort.

- How would your request provide greater benefit to them? *What about the site as a whole -- what benefit would your suggestion give?

The intention behind it was to promote a sort of coding competition for people who are learning something new; **in a given area**. It may delay the response by few minutes or maybe an hour, but maybe it *encourage* **not force** people who are just learning something new to try even newer things.

- The burden of proof of benefit is on you, the asker, and I would posit that until you provide answers to the above and to other issues, answers that would suffice, the response to your suggestion, in my mind (and quite probably most everyone else's) would be "no"

All true. The point is if you know you are going to get very quick answers, you seem to try less on your own. And if you get downvotes, you get demotivated (learn from it sure, but demotivated nevertheless).

[image]

Comment: nope, we don't. Either the question stands on its own, without any training wheels or it gets closed/deleted eventually. Any other approach simply does not work on a site that gets several thousand questions per day: those "simple" questions are usually either duplicates (should be closed), mega-duplicates (should be deleted), or of no value to anyone but the OP (delete as well).

Comment: I understand. Although to clarify: I thought of this too. That's why it is not a restriction; but a suggestion. Just like "Be Nice."; I know whether I am nice or not :) Who thinks who is new and who is experienced depends on their point of view. But you would get this message when **you** are answering this message so you can decide. Nobody would be stopping anyone.

Comment: *"The intention was to in a way promote friendly small competition"* ... competition already exists and is done by voting on the answers. And users can already try new stuff and answer questions in unknown fields, nothing hinders them.

Comment: @Tom yes (competition) exists. But it's as though giving some more time to people who want to try new things. Something you already know. Voting is good but it can have lot of other effects too. Take this question for example. This was a suggestion. I tagged it as `Feature Request`. I posted it here because this seems to be the site to post this. Now, so far I have gotten -6 points (May be it will be -6 million in day or two; I don't mind); for trying to give suggestion :). So, voting is cold. Not _everyone_ would be able to bare it. But maybe it's way I look at things vs how others do.

Comment: I'm sorry you interpret it as "cold" when you request feedback and folks are giving it via votes, which is normal on meta.

Comment: How exactly would the system judge if something is simple? Users won't like if they are constantly shown that message on questions that are in fact not simple (at least according to them). If the criteria would be new users that would be wrong too as their questions too can be complex. If the criteria were to show the message to all people with high rep in the question tags then that too would be irritating.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I can choose to look at something in different way. That does not make it wrong, it's just point of view. Just so that I am clear, that does not mean I give up. And yes, I would not mind getting downvotes for my technical questions\answers. I was referring to this specific question. It is as though you go to someone you know give a suggestion and they give you downvote. Okay. So, from next time either I have to _somehow_ get it reviewed _before_ or shut up ? :) And this is for giving a suggestion for only way it is possible? :) It's like MS teams: you can downvote\like _each_ msg!!:)

Comment: Where did someone, or I say that your POV is wrong? Do you know what a strawman is?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I think I am somehow not being able to explain :). The message is appearing __to you__ when __you are answering__. It's upto you. It's NOT restriction. It's a suggestion. Just like "Be Nice."

Comment: In addition to the questions that I closed this as a duplicate of, I think it's very important to emphasize that the age of questions doesn't matter here, and neither does the speed of the response time. For more background on the phenomenon known as the Fastest Gun In The West (FGITW), also see [my answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408265). I'm also very uncomfortable with your implicitly linking this to being "nice". There's nothing "nice" about choosing not to answer a question when you could post a good answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Okay. Unfortunately, I cannot do anything about your uncomfortable-ness. I am expressing my intention. Not out of fear but out of the fact that stackoverflow has helped me a lot over the years. I can shut up but then I would not be contributing. Yes, I can very well be penalized for feeling that way, but hey, can't really change that nor can shut up :)

Comment: I am certainly not telling you to shut up. Constructive feedback and suggestions are welcome, even when they are disagreed with.

Comment: Related: *[Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731)*

Answer (score 11):

Your question asks for a policy change but provides no information in support of, offers no rationale for this request, which begs the question -- why make the suggestion?

More specifically,

- What defines who is "old" and who is "young"?
- Why should there be limits to anyone answering a question?
- Why would it matter who was "first" to answer a question?
- What about the question asker and the future visitors with similar problems, what benefit would they obtain?
- How would your request provide greater benefit to them?
  *What about the site as a whole, what benefit would your suggestion give?

The burden of proof of benefit is on you, the asker, and I would posit that until you provide answers to the above and to other issues, answers that would suffice, the response to your suggestion, in my mind (and quite probably most everyone else's) would be "no"

Comment: Hey, you're too old to answer this question!

Comment: Dang! Busted again!

Comment: yes, you both are. be nice :)