# Very inappropriate titled question edited and avoided moderator intervention

Tags: discussion, moderation, grace-period

Question: [Why is rspec calling two controller actions at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410792/rspec-calling-two-controller-actions-at-once)

The original question had a title that included very inappropriate and racist terms - the -4 on it is indication of the reaction it got. The question was flagged, but by the time the flag was reviewed the question title was edited by the OP - so the flag was rejected with 'no evidence'.

I can't see the edit history for this, but should a moderator be able to? It seems incorrect that such blatant racism edited out within a couple of minutes is able to bypass appropriate intervention.

Could the moderator have seen the history? Or are users able to bypass moderation due to latency in reviewing flags?

Comment: If it was edited within the first 5 minutes, no, even moderators couldn't see it. Though comments and closures break the grace period.

Comment: It would of been within the first 5 minutes I suspect.

Comment: Perhaps flags, especially rude/spam flags, ought to break the grace period too.

Comment: It was indeed edited within the grace period, and moderators cannot see those edits. @Shog9 confirmed the original vulgar title via moderator chat, this appears to be an annoying corner case where moderators don't really have the information needed to verify a rude-or-abusive flag and cannot easily obtain it.

Comment: I think that ChrisF's idea would be a good feature request, making rude and spam flags break the grace period, because that's something that really should be caught.

Comment: @DavyM [this has already been proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307402/2301450), FWIW

Comment: Given the comments, it sounds like this is in essence a duplicate feature request post and should be closed as such.

Comment: Your post asks a direct question of "why does this happen", which is not the same as the feature request.  I'd prefer this stay open (and even be answered) as an additional argument for the implementation of the other feature request.

Comment: Although, it seems like maybe Shog knows more details?  Perhaps SO employees have more information?  Or just got alerted by a bot or something?

Comment: what did they even say that was super racist?  Where they literally trying to use the title for racist agenda?  If so they should still be reprimanded.  The edit history doesn't show any racist terms as far as I can see...

Comment: "White men can't jump"

Comment: @snb: "The edit history doesn't show any racist terms as far as I can see..." **That's the entire point of this question.** FYI, if you really want to know, the n-word was used somewhere in the title.

Comment: @BoltClock what was the context of the usage?  Shog9 says "In this case, the author clearly wised up to their mistake" which makes me think they were using it as an expletive instead of an agenda?  It would surprise me that this person hasn't been hit with some sort of suspension or something if that wasn't the case.

Comment: @snb: It was indeed used as an expletive. But, understandably, such is the nature of the n-word that many consider it grotesquely offensive and completely unacceptable regardless of usage, and using it especially on a site like this is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The entire purpose of the grace period is to allow authors to see their post in the wild, immediately realize that they've made a terrible mistake, and correct it without penalty.

So... This is pretty much by-design.

That said, it *is* possible for someone to abuse it, and that has happened:

- post something benign and edit at *n* minutes to something else, hoping it's fallen off the homepage by then...
- post something offensive, edit to benign at *n* minutes to avoid penalty

At some point, this stops being a forgivable mistake and starts being a blatant attempt to hurt others. Fortunately, [there are ways to end the grace period early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876) and if need-be we can even dig through the logs to determine if something was missed. Both of these have come in handy in the past when dealing with persistent trolling and abuse.

In this case, the author clearly wised up to their mistake and corrected the problem themselves (within two minutes of originally posting it), so I don't think anything further is necessary. I've marked your flag "disputed" to reflect the fact that it was raised in good faith.

Comment: Thanks for the response - the status of the flag was not important, what was posted was.

Comment: Hmmm, if there is a knowledge of the grace period, then will be probably best step to make an screenshot I guess..

Comment: Screenshots don't really bring anything and can be easily edited, they can't be really used as evidence.